# depth first tree search

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble implementing a recursive depth-first search on a [tree structure](http://cbio.ufs.ac.za/live_docs/nbn_tut/trees.html) in python 2.7, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Code

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value,children=[]):
        self.value=value
        self.children=children
    def __repr__ (self,level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret +=child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret  

    def search(self,st):
        if self.value==st:
            return True
        else:
            if not self.children:
                return False
            else:               
                for child in self.children:
                    self.search(st)
```

sample data structure (for simple pasting):

```
tree = node("fashion",[
    node("garment",[
        node("t-shirt"),
        node("shorts")]),
    node("designer",[
        node("Ralf"),
        node("tommy"),
        node("joe")])
    ])
```

EDIT: the problem is that I'm ending in an infinate loop when searching, for example:

```
tree.search("garment")
```

EDIT 2: update to fix the recursion not advancing (thanks Ben!), but not getting a False answer to tree.search("joe")

```
    def search(self,st):
    if self.value==st:
        return True
    else:
        if self.children:
            for child in self.children:
                return child.search(st)             
        else:               
            return False
```

EDIT 3: astute observations from Sharth have led me to

```
def search(self,st):
    if self.value==st:
        return True
    for child in self.children:
        if child.search(st):
            return True         
    return False
```

Which works great, but searching

```
>>>tree.search("p")
```

produces

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       tree.search("p")   File "", line 15, in search
>       if child.search(st): AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'search'

why is that happening?

EDIT4: works when using the above data structure, but fails with a third level of data, i.e.

```
tree = node("fashion",[
    node("garment",[
        node("t-shirt"),
        node("shorts")]),
    node("designer",[
        node("Ralf"),
        node("tommy"),
        node("joe"),[
        node("fresh")]
    ])
    ])
```

edit 5: messed up the braces in edit four.

Comment: Your recursion doesn't move towards a terminating condition, you're searching in the direct children of the root always.

Comment: thanks Ben, although now I'm getting false positives having changed to:

def search(self,st):
  if self.value==st:
   return True
  else:
   if not self.children:
    return False
   else:    
    for child in self.children:
     return child.search(st)

when using >>>tree.search("tommy")
i get      >>>False

Comment: You might want to post the edit. Can you also post the repr of tree? So we can see it is indeed building your structure correctly

Comment: by adding a print to the search function, you can sort of see a stack trace: fashion, garment, t-shirt, False. So you see your function is ending prematurely. As soon as it hits a leaf, the false is propagated up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, 3 issues have been fixed:

1. [Mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198)
2. When looping, we need to call `child.search(st)`, not `self.search(st)`.
3. We don't want to only look at the first child (as your 2nd edit does), we want to return success on the first one that is true. If the first one is false, we want to try the next..

So, the code:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children or []

    def search(self, st):
        if self.value == st:
            return True
        for child in self.children:
             if child.search(st):
                 return True
        return False
```

Comment: +1 for the `self.children = children or []` suggestion. I don't use python enough to know the idioms for things like default parameters, so this was helpful! I'm pretty sure JavaScript uses pretty much the same idiom.

Comment: looks like a great solution, hoevwer, i get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'search' on if child.search(st): using tree.search("p")

Comment: @mikedotonline: When you get that error, what is `self.children` and `child`? I suspect that you have nested lists.

Comment: @sharth I added a child to joe. when removed, it works, but not when child present... the __repr__ fails too. i suspect they are related now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your search function isn't actually searching the children. Try this instead:

```
def search(self,st):
    if self.value==st:
        return True
    else:
        if not self.children:
            return False
        else:               
            return any(child.search(st) for child in self.children)
```

Notice that the last line has been modified to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in conjunction with the built-in function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) in order to search each of the children in sequence, stopping as soon as one of them results in a `True`.

***The key difference here is that we call `child.search(st)` instead of `self.search(st)`.***

Also note that you really don't need a separate case for when `children` is empty, so you could do this instead:

```
def search(self,st):
    if self.value==st:
        return True
    else:
        return any(child.search(st) for child in self.children)
```

This can be further simplified:

```
def search(self,st):
    return self.value==st or any(child.search(st) for child in self.children)
```

When you're returning a boolean literal it's a good sign that you can probably simplify by using `and` / `or` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please set children to None and not a list. Its very dangerous to have a mutable argument as a default parameter. See [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198) for reference. The value of children may not be an empty list, even if its intended to be.

Comment: This is a good point, but should probably be a comment rather than an answer.