# objective-c creates array with ellipse

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am extremely new to Objective-C and iOS programming. The tutorial I am using has the following syntax for creating a NSString array representing the ranks of a deck of cards. My question is whether it is valid:

```
NSArray *rankStrings =@[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",...,@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
```

The reason for the question is that xCode is giving a red exclamation mark which says `Expected expression`. I don't want to mis-learn that ellipses are unacceptable. So I am asking here to know exactly why I am getting the error.

For comparison, python has range functions for creating lists. So maybe the ellipse here is comparable: I don't know. So can someone point out what's wrong with the declaration? Whether it is the ellipse, or how I am using them, or something else?

Comment: Your book author was just too lazy to continue the array. You need to replace the ... with @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the [Python's advanced slicing operation using an ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112316/1187415) does not exist in Objective-C.
Your code

```
NSArray *rankStrings = @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",...,@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
```

is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
NSArray *rankStrings =@[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",...,@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
```

with

```
NSArray *rankStrings =@[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
```

Objective-C can not continue the array for you on it's own. The book author was just a little too laze to continue so he inserted the ...

Comment: Yeah no probs! Glad you found an answer here on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post more about your code?

and you are using

```
NSArray * @[objects ....]
```

and I am sure your Array

```
NSArray *rankStrings =@[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",...,@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
```

is right.

Comment: It would be right if he wanted to create the array without the ellipsis. But as there are no automatic slicing operations in obj-C, it's wrong. (it's about the ... within the array)