# if-else, using the True and False statements on python. skulpt.org

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my code where I had to create it so it allows

1. The user inputs the lengths of three sides of a triangle as Length1, Length2 and Length3
2. If any two sides have the same length the program outputs "Isosceles"
3. Otherwise the program outputs "Not isosceles"

However, the output part doesn't seem like working.
I am new to this type of coding, so please help?

```
Length1 = raw_input()
Length2 = raw_input()
Length3 = raw_input()

print Length1
print Length2
print Length3
print Length1 == Length2
print Length2 == Length3
print Length1 == Length3

if Length1 == Length2 is True:
    print "Isosceles"
else: 
    print "Not Isosceles"  

if Length2 == Length3 is True:
    print "Isosceles"
else:
    print "Not Isosceles"

if Length1 == Length3 is True:
    print "Isosceles"
else:
    print "Not Isosceles"
```

Comment: just use `if Length1 == Length2`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Python interprets

```
if Length1 == Length2 is True:
```

like

```
if Length1 == Length2 and Length2 is True:
```

[Comparison operators, like `<`, `==`, or `is` are chained.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101945/1639625) This is very useful for, e.g. `a < b < c`, but it can also result in some unexpected behaviour, as in your case.

Change those checks to

```
if (Length1 == Length2) is True:
```

or better, just use

```
if Length1 == Length2:
```

---

Alternatively, you could just count the number of *distinct* sides using a `set`:

```
distinct_sides = len(set([Length1, Length2, Length3]))
if distinct_sides == 1:
    print "Equilateral"
if distinct_sides == 2:
    print "Isosceles"
if distinct_sides == 3:
    print "Scalene"
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the actual problem, not just proposing better code.

Comment: The OP asks if any of the two sides are the same it should output ` print "Isosceles"`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sure, my version is just a little bit more concise. Of course you can change it to `if distinct_sides <= 2: print "Isosceles"; else: ...`

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a function that checks each pair to see if they are equal

```
def isosceles(x1, x2, x3):
    return x1 == x2 or x2 == x3 or x1 == x3

# slightly faster version since it returns after the first True
def isosceles(x1, x2, x3):
    return any(x1 == x2, x2 == x3, x1 == x3)
```

Make sure you convert the inputs to `int` so you aren't comparing `string` values

```
Length1 = int(raw_input())
Length2 = int(raw_input())
Length3 = int(raw_input())
```

Then call your function

```
if isosceles(Length1, Length2, Length3):
    print "Isosceles"
else:
    print "Not isosceles"
```

Comment: "1" == "1" will still be True

Comment: Yes it will, but I can see them coming back about 10 minutes from now with "why is my hypotenuse function throwing a type error?"

Comment: well it is still worth pointing out that ints as strings will compare equally without casting.

Comment: "# slightly faster version since it returns after the first True" the same holds for `... or ... or ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
if Length1 == Length2: # don't use `if Length1 == Length2 is True:`
    print "Isosceles"

elif Length2 == Length3:
    print "Isosceles"

elif Length1 == Length3:
    print "Isosceles"
else:
    print "Not Isosceles"
```

You need to use `elif`, `elif's` are only evaluated if the previous statement is False, `if's` are always evaluated.

`if Length1 == Length2 is True:` is not the same as `if Length1 == Length2`:

Your statements would only be True if both `Length1`  and `Length2` were  `= True`.

Comment: "Unless Length2 is actually False your statements will always evaluate to True" Maybe I misunderstood you, but I think this is not correct. Unless `Length2` is `True`, it will always return false. E.g., `3 == 3 is True` -> `False`

Comment: @tobias_k, yes should have put True