# Check if number is between given range

Tags: python

I came across an answer that we can check if number is between a given range by following method 10<=n<=100. I want to know how exactly this statement gets executed in python.I'm new to python and know how to code in java.

From the answers, I came to know that this feature is called chaining comparison operators. Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "*how exactly this statement gets executed*"?

Comment: Check the first answer of [Hidden features of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is 'how exactly this statement gets executed'

```
import dis

def f(n):
    return 10<=n<=100

print(dis.dis(f))
```

which gives

```
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             17 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   21 ROT_TWO
             22 POP_TOP
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

but did you really want to know that?

[Chaining comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101945) may be a good reference.

> It's really translating into `10 < n and n < 100`

Answer (score 1):

In python, these kind of double conditions are executed as consecutives ands, so:

```
10 <= n <= 100
```

is equal to:

```
(10 <= n) and (n <= 100)
```

And it returns a boolean that can either be `True` or `False` depending on whether the statement is met.