# Strange unknown lambda syntax

Tags: python, lambda, syntax

I know what this does (makes `k` refer to then actual value instead of last value) but what is this syntax called?
Comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/215326/2375119

```
funcs = [] 
for k in range(10):
     funcs.append(lambda k = k: k)

>>> funcs[7]()
7 # not 9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax has no name in particular. It's one of the ways of binding closures to their arguments; [Python *closures* are late binding](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

That syntax is a way of strapping the current iteratee value to each `lambda` by passing it as a default argument when creating the lambda. Since **default arguments are evaluated when the function is created**, the value sticks to the function.