# Looping over a list and saving elements that meet a condition to a new list

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop over a list and save *some* elements to a new list: the ones that are at more than 50 greater than the previous value.  My current code saves only the first value.  I want `[0, 76, 176, 262, 349]`.

```
list = [0, 76, 91, 99, 176, 192, 262, 290, 349]
new_list = []
for i in list:
    if ((i+1)-i) > 50:
        new_list.extend([i])
```

Comment: How can `((i + 1) - i)` ever be greater than 50? The answer is always 1.

Comment: This code prints an empty list, since your `if` condition is never met.

Comment: Could you add to the cuestion a real example with numbers of what condition must be true?

Comment: At a guess, you intend `i` to be an index of the list, and `i + 1` is the next item in the list?

Comment: As an aside, don't do `new_list.extend([i])`, just use `new_list.append(i)`

Comment: [**enumerate**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967144/5195706) and find salvation.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

> What I want is to save the values 0, 76, 176, 262, and 349.

So it sounds like you want to iterate over the list, and if the current element is **greater than its preceding element by 50** then save it to the list and repeat. *This solution assumes the original list is sorted.* Let's turn this into some code.

```
lst = [0, 76, 91, 99, 176, 192, 262, 290, 349]
new_lst = []
for i, num in enumerate(lst):
    if i == 0 or num - lst[i-1] > 50:
        new_lst.append(num)

print(new_lst)
# [0, 76, 176, 262, 349]
```

The interesting part here is the conditional within the loop:

```
if i == 0 or num - lst[i-1] > 50:
```

The first part considers if we're at the first element, in which case I assume you want to add the element no matter what. Otherwise, get the  difference between our current element and the **previous** element in the original list, and check if the difference is greater than 50. In both cases, we want to append the element to the list (hence the **or**).

### Notes

- You should avoid using `list` as a variable so you don't shadow the built-in Python type.
- `lst.extend([num])` is better written as `lst.append(num)`.
- `enumerate(lst)` allows you to easily get both the index and value of each element in a list (or any iterable).

Comment: creative solution, assuming ```list``` is sorted

Comment: @RemedialBear Thanks for the reminder about the sorting :)

Comment: Thanks so much thats exactly what I needed

Comment: I don't think this works as specified.  Consider the input list `[0, 76, 91, 99, 120, 150, 220]`.  The correct output is `[0, 76, 220]`, but your solution ignores the chain 91-120 and include the value `150` in the output.  `120` and `150` are not 50 apart, but this code compares only against the previously included value.

Comment: @Prune I would need clarification from OP, as the question could be interpreted both ways at this point. Either way, it'd be a simple change to the inner loop condition.

Comment: @Prune After re-reading the question a few times I realized you are right, I've edited my solution to properly answer the question :)

Answer (score 3):

The statement `if ((i+1)-i) > 50` will always evaluate to `if (1 > 50)` which is false. You're looking for the next element in `list`, but `i` is simply the *value* of the current element. Try something like the `tee()` function in the `itertools` library to get multiple values, or something like

```
list = [0, 76, 91, 99, 176, 192, 262, 290, 349]
new_list = []
for i in range(len(list)):
    print (i, list[i])
    if i == 0 or (list[i] - list[i-1]) > 50:
        new_list.append(list[i])
```

Keep in mind, I didn't add any checks for whether there *is* an `i + 1` element, so you may need to do some error handling.

**EDIT**

This is my final edit. I would like to thank @Prune for enforcing standards :)

First, the code in PyCharm:

[image: Code in PyCharm CE]

Second, the console output:

[image: Console output]

Comment: The new list would contain duplicates, and consider using `append` instead of `extend` with `list[i]`, because `list[i]` is not a list.

Comment: thanks @roganjosh, I made the edits. Kinda sucks when people downvote without mentioning what was wrong

Comment: @RemedialBear _always_ worth checking it quickly for the 10 secs it takes. Makes it hard to beat the super-keen on getting the first answer, though, but you'd have found those errors yourself immediately I guess :)

Comment: This code has both a syntax error and a semantic error.  Parentheses are unbalanced in the `if`, and you can't `extend` with a scalar.

Comment: I suspect this would miss `349`.

Comment: @Prune okay, I think I've got it this time...hopefully I get a passing grade now

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if (list[i+1]-list[i]) > 50:
        new_list.append(list[i])
if list[-1] - new_list[-1] > 50:
    new_list.append(list[-1]) #for the last element of list
```

Of course, the code can be made better. But this should work.

Comment: Why are you including a `set` operation?  This indicates an untidiness within the loop, adding values twice.

Comment: @Prune I mentioned about making the code better. I just wanted it to be simple enough for the person who asked the problem. But since you mentioned it, I think I should do an edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition inside a list comprehension.
Also, do *not* give a variable the same name (list) as a built-in type.

```
my_list = [0, 76, 91, 99, 176, 192, 262, 290, 349]

# Start with the first element;
#   then grab each element more than 50 greater than the previous one.

new_list = [my_list[0]]
new_list.extend([my_list[i] for i in range(1, len(my_list))
                 if my_list[i] - my_list[i-1] > 50])
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[0, 76, 176, 262, 349]
```

Comment: list comprehension might be a little complex for a new python programmer :p but it's also a great tool to learn

Comment: I realize that; this answer is a stretching exercise.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
l = [0, 76, 91, 99, 176, 192, 262, 290, 349]
o = list(l[0]) + [a for a, b in zip(l[1:], l[:-1]) if a - b - 50 > 0]
```

output: `[0, 76, 176, 262, 349]`