# Custom URL when generating from one php file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok, so I've got a file named generate.php. It takes values from the database and generates a dynamic page based on the database id contained in the url.

Link example:

```
<a href="/pages/generate.php?id=1"></a>
```

So where it lands is domain.com/pages/generate.php?id=1. I'd like to use custom urls generated from the title like, for example, stackoverflow has: `(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python).`

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: search for 'slug', 'htaccess rewrite' and you'll find plenty of tutorials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .htaccess, to rewrite the URL, to have the custom address.
example:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Index.php / $ 1 [QSA, L]`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens to end up here:

https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners