# Understanding list comprehension that uses recursion

Tags: recursion, list-comprehension

I am currently learning about list comprehension and come across this line of recursive code:

```
ans = [sort(a, i + 1) for a in ans]
```

I have tried substituting that line with the following:

```
for a in ans:
    ans = (sort(a, i + 1))
```

Could somebody please help me understand where I have made a mistake?

thanks!

Comment: It's not recursive; it just creates a new list, then assigns that to the same name.

Comment: Ah, I understand! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The for loop and the list comprehension are not equivalent.

Imagine we have:

```
>>> def sort(a, _): return 2*a
...
>>> i=0
```

Then:

```
>>> ans=list(range(5))
>>> ans = [sort(a, i + 1) for a in ans]
>>> ans
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

But:

```
>>> ans=list(range(5))
>>> for a in ans: ans=(sort(a, i+1))
>>> ans
8
```

The list comprehension basically:

- applies `sort(a, i+1)` to every `a` in `ans`
- then assigns the result to the variable `ans` itself.

As said by @chepner in a comment, there is no recursion here<sup>[1]</sup>. It's equivalent to:

```
>>> ans=list(range(5))
>>> new_ans = [sort(a, i + 1) for a in ans]
>>> ans = new_ans
>>> new_ans
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

While the for loop:

- iterates over `ans`:
- assigns `sort(a, i+1)` to `ans` for every `a`

Hence, the assignements give: `ans = sort(ans[0], i+1)`, then `ans = sort(ans[1], i+1)`, ..., `ans = sort(ans[-1], i+1)` where `ans[-1]` is the last element of the original `ans`<sup>2</sup>.

The loop equivalent of your list comprehension is:

```
>>> ans=list(range(5))
>>> new_ans=[]
>>> for a in ans: new_ans.append(sort(a, i+1))
>>> ans = new_ans # assignement here
>>> ans
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> A function may use recursion, but I'm not sure what recursion would mean for a list comprehension unless you use some dirty hack: for the record https://stackoverflow.com/a/221874/6914441.

<sup>[2]</sup>  Note that the reassignement of the variable `ans` does not modify the original list:

- when the loop begins, Python creates an iterator over the list and keeps a reference on the list;
- when the `ans` is reaffected, the for loop has still the reference on the original list.

It would be different if you modify the list from within the loop body (**strongly discouraged**):

```
>>> xs=list(range(5))
>>> for x in xs: print(x, xs);_=xs.pop(0)
...
0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2 [1, 2, 3, 4]
4 [2, 3, 4]
```

We remove the first element for every iteration, but the index continues to grow:

```
[*0*, 1, 2, 3, 4] # then pop 0
[1, *2*, 3, 4] # then pop 1
[2, 3, *4*] # then pop 2
```