# What exactly is going on with the indentation here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The second code tries to print prime numbers between the range but it fails to do that and prints some numbers multiple times between the range
The first code,where the indentation seems absurd runs perfectly and I don't understand how the indentation is working for this

```
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):     
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           break
   else:
         print(num)
```

---

```
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):     
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           break
       else:
           print(num)
```

Comment: You can read about for-else statement here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/114420/5079316

Comment: Thank you. I just found out about the else-for relationship just as I finished posting this and then I couldn't delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing "absurd" about the indentation of the first code is that the final `print` is indented more than needed.

`else`, when applied to a loop, is executed when the loop is exhausted (as opposed to broken out of).  So in the first code, as long as `num` isn't divisible by any `i`, it will be printed, which is what you want.

`else`, when applied to an `if`, has no effect on the enclosing loop.  In particular, the inner loop will continue, meaning `num` will get printed for *every* `i` that doesn't divide `num` evenly.

Answer (score 3):

Python has an `else` clause not only for `if` but also `for` loops as well. The `for ... else` clause triggers if the loop is *not* left forcefully - via `return`, `raise` or `break` - but iteration finishes normally.

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
else:
    print('done')

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        break  # break skips the else clause
else:
    print('done')
```

For your code, this means:

- In the first case, `else` triggers if *none* of the `i` trigger `(num % i) == 0`.
- In the second case, `else` triggers if *one* (or more) of the `i` does not trigger `(num % i) == 0`.

Comment: "... second case, else triggers *for every value of i that* does..."

Comment: @ScottHunter It was not meant exclusively. I've made the wording more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting that if any number below a number does not gets divisible by that number then *print it*

or you are finding if there are any roots of a number

In the Second code you are passing code sequence to else case every time you are checking divisibility with a number. However as expected you have to print the number only after the number passes the if condition on all numbers below it.