# Strange chained comparison

Tags: python, comparison

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 3
>>> c = 2
>>> b > a == c
True
>>>
```

Is this true that `b > a == c` is equal to `a < b and c == a` because it's a chained comparison?

This doesn't make sense to me because of `==` comparison, I would expect that `b > a == c` is equal to `(b > a) == c` or `b > (a == c)`.

Comment: Chaining works with any comparison operator, `a op b op c` is equivalent to `(a op b) and (b op c)`

Comment: With the slight difference in behavior that `a op b op c` only has to compute/load `b` once, where `(a op b) and (b op c)` would have to do so twice. Specific answer on duplicate that addresses your problem is [Chaining comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101945/364696).

Comment: According to the comment from @Barmar operator priority doesn't work in this case, because it's a chained comparison which results to `(a < b) and (c == a)`

Comment: @Massifox: Incorrect. All the comparison operators (aside from boolean operators `or`, `and` and `not`) [have equal precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The parentheses simply prevent the chaining from operating at all, so you simply have one unchained comparison within the parentheses, with the result used in an unchained comparison outside the parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

python is correcting your comparison automatically with if (b>a) AND (a==c)

Comment: "correcting" implies the code was wrong in some way and Python had to fix it. The Python language spec intentionally supports this design; it's just unusual (and likely a programmer mistake) to use it to chain greater-than with equality testing.

Comment: "and likely a programmer mistake". That's the thing: PyCharm suggests to simplify `a < b and c == a` and it looks wrong.

Comment: @warvariuc: The PyCharm simplification is largely correct (aside from `a < b` possibly behaving differently from `b > a`, same for `a == c` vs. `c == a`). It has to load `a` twice, but it's less confusing. If the PyCharm simplification is wrong, it probably means you didn't write what you intended, and need additional parentheses to correct it to `(b > a) == c` or `b > (a == c)` (assuming one of those was the intent). Comparison chaining is much more intuitive for stuff like range testing, e.g. `if 0 < x < 10:` as a simple way to check if `x` is between `0` and `10` (exclusive).

Comment: @ShadowRanger See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37991 That's where my question came from.