# Expression valued differently and unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7.4.

I can't figure out why

2 > 3 > -1 == False

while

(2 > 3) > -1 == True

and

2 > (3 > -1) == True
??

Comment: Because `True` evaluates as 1 and `False` as 0. Or in other words, the value of True object is 1 and the value of False object is 0. Try `int(True)` or `int(False)`.

Comment: This is a variation of a common FAQ and possibly should be closed as a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084423/strange-chained-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `0 == False` and `1 == True`. You will see that boolean are a subclass of `int` in Python.
Moreover, operators are read from left to right and the parentheses have higher precedence over the `>` operator.

So the last two ones read as follow:

```
(2 > 3) > -1  -> True > -1  -> 1 > -1  -> True
2 > (3 > -1)  -> 2 > True   -> 2 > 1   -> True
```

For the first one you gave, Python reads it as following:

```
2 > 3 > -1  -> (2 > 3) and (3 > -1)  -> False and (3 > -1)  -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to chaining comparison `a op b op c` is equivalent to `(a op b) and (b op c)`

- `2 > 3 > -1` --> `(2 > 3) and (3 > -1)` which results in `False and True` which gives `False`
- `(2 > 3) > -1` --> Python will compute the brackets first `(2 > 3) = 0 or False` then `(0 > -1) = True or 1`
- `2 > (3 > -1)` --> `(3 > -1) = True or 1` then `(2 > 1) = True or 1`