# How to create a Python class method that can use but doesn't require an extra argument

Tags: python, class

My brief requires me to create a method that

> accepts an amount and description. If no description is given, it
> should default to an empty string. The method should append an object
> to the ledger list in the form of {"amount": amount, "description":
> description}.

I have therefore created this function:

```
 def deposit(self,amount,description):
   if description == "":
     newdict = {"amount":amount,"description":""}
     self.ledger.append(newdict)
   else:
     newdict = {"amount":amount,"description":description}
     self.ledger.append(newdict)
```

However, the test `clothing.deposit(25.55)` clearly only uses one argument, the amount, and expects me to leave a blank description, but as is it returns the error `TypeError: deposit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'description'`. But if a description is required, I also have to be ready to use it. How do I setup my method so it can use the extra argument, description, but if it isn't given it can safely ignore it?

Comment: Can we stop using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python as a reason for closing Python questions?  Even if the answer is there it's unreasonable to expect someone to be able to find it there.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can assign default values to the arguments of a method definition. Change your method signature to

```
def deposit(self, amount, description="")
```

This should give the expected behavior.