# hash assignment when (key => value) are stored in an array? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have **hash (@post) of hashes** where I want to keep the order of the hash's keys in the array (@post_csv_order) and also want to keep the **relationship key => value in the array**.

I don't know the final number of both @post hashes and key => value elements in the array.

I don't know how to assign the hash in a loop for all elements in the array. One by one `@post_csv_order[0][0] => @post_csv_order[0][1]` works nicely.

```
#  require 'rubygems'
require 'pp'

@post = {}

forum_id = 123           #only sample values.... to make this sample script work
post_title = "Test post"

@post_csv_order = [
  ["ForumID" , forum_id],
  ["Post title", post_title]  
]

if @post[forum_id] == nil
  @post[forum_id] = {
    @post_csv_order[0][0] => @post_csv_order[0][1],
    @post_csv_order[1][0] => @post_csv_order[1][1]
    #@post_csv_order.map {|element| element[0] => element[1]}
    #@post_csv_order.each_index {|index|        @post_csv_order[index][0] => @post_csv_order[index][1] }
  }
end

pp @post
```

desired hash assignment should be like that

**`{123=>{"Post title"=>"Test post", "ForumID"=>123}}`**

Comment: Please edit your question to format it correctly...

Comment: Thank you,it happens quite often that the formatting is not correct after submitting. I have to double check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but I guess you want to convert a 2d array in a hash.

So suppose you have an array such as:

```
array = [[:foo,1],[:bar,2],[:baz,3]]
```

You can build an hash with:

```
hash = array.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e[0]] = e[1]; h}
# => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}
```

And you can retrieve the keys in correct order with:

```
keys = array.inject([]) {|a,e| a << e[0] }
=> [:foo, :bar, :baz]
```

Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: @paradigmatic: maybe, maybe you didn't understand fully but you fully answered :-) All I needed was `hash = array.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e[0]] = e[1]; h}` which I changed in my sample code to `@post[forum_id] = @post_csv_order.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e[0]] = e[1]; h}` and it does exactly I wanted to do. I will check it in the whole project script tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: The other way to build a hash from an array of arrays of key, value pairs is: Hash[*array.flatten]

Comment: @Wayne: indeed, there is an easier way with Hash[], but the flatten is not necessary since 1.8.7 (and it is actually dangerous, if any of your key/value is an array) See my answer

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: wow. `@post[forum_id] = Hash[*@post_csv_order.flatten]` works really nicely.Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
[ [:foo,1],[:bar,2],[:baz,3] ].to_h  #=> {:foo => 1, :bar => 2, :baz => 3}
```

**Note**: This was introduced in Ruby 2.1.0. For older Ruby, you can use my `backports` gem and [`require 'backports/2.1.0/array/to_h'`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports), or else use [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
array = [[:foo,1],[:bar,2],[:baz,3]]
# then
Hash[ array ]  #= > {:foo => 1, :bar => 2, :baz => 3}
```

This is available in Ruby 1.8.7 and later. If you are still using Ruby 1.8.6 you could [`require "backports/1.8.7/hash/constructor"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports), but you might as well use the `to_h` backport.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: it looks nice. What would be the code in my case? `@post[forum_id] = @post_csv_order` gives me hash of arrays not hash of hashes.

Comment: You did you call Hash[] ? See my updated answer.
Don't forget to require backports if using 1.8.6

Comment: I tried `@post[forum_id] = Hash[ @post_csv_order ]` and now I tried `@post[forum_id] ||= Hash[ @post_csv_order ]`. Both gives me `odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError)`

Comment: hm, why did you use `||` in front of = ?

Comment: odd number of arguments => I believe you are using Ruby 1.8.6? You need to `require "backports"` beforehand.

||= see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby/1941479#1941479

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: you're right,it's working now.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Answers summary

working code #1

```
@post[forum_id] = @post_csv_order.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e[0]] = e[1]; h}
```

working code #2

`@post[forum_id] = Hash[*@post_csv_order.flatten]`

working code #3

`@post[forum_id] ||= Hash[ @post_csv_order ] #requires 'require "backports"'`