# Rails: Many-to-many flattening with only the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model object which is linked to a list of countries in a many-to-many relationship. The countries are keyed by their [ISO 3166 alpha-2 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

The thing I'd like to accomplish is to save to use of a Country class and table, and only have my object have an accessor in the form of `object.countries` that will return an array of strings, e.g: `["IL", "US", "IT", ... ]`.

Essentially, a sort of `has_and_belongs_to_many` action with only the join table.
Is this possible?

Is there a best practice in the case of country lists?

Comment: consider a standard `has_many` and overwrite the `countries` method in your `object` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I eventually solved it, I created a countries table in the database, as I preferred a HABTM relationship.

But to simplify things, I overrode the `<<` operator on the collection so I could just push country codes as string or array of strings (`object.country << 'IL'`):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many(:countries) do
  def <<(country)
    if [*country].all? {|c| c.is_a?(String) }

      countries = Country.where(:code => country)
      concat(*countries)

    else

      concat(country)

    end
  end
end
```

You might recognize that `[*...]` trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby/64458#64458).
Passing `concat(*countries)` also makes Rails insert all the rows in a single transaction, which is a nice bonus.

And added a function to return a simplified hash of codes to countries:

```
def countries_hash
  return self.countries.map {|c| { c.code => c.name }}.inject({}) {|hash, elem| hash.merge!(elem)}
end
```

Of course I'd be glad to hear any suggestions.