# Rails Association Extensions: Override a HABTM assignment (collection=) method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, overriding

[In a question I've previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970965/rails-many-to-many-flattening-with-only-the-join-table/8107758#8107758), I used an association extension to override a HABTM collection's append (`<<`) method (Also, [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2890761/242826)):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many(:countries) do
  def <<(country)
    if [*country].all? {|c| c.is_a?(String) }
      countries = Country.where(:code => country)
      concat(*countries)
    else
      concat(country)
    end
  end
end
```

This is probably not encouraged, but my question is, how can one override, if even possible, the assignment operator, so I can do `countries = ['IL', 'US']` with the same results?

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I don't really know what you want to do

Comment: The idea is to have a collection relationship to which I could assign both an array of objects (`[obj1, obj2, ...]`) and an array of object keys (`[key1, key2, ...]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be something like:

```
def =(countries)
  values = countries.kind_of?(Hash) ? countries.values : countries
  values.each do |country|
    self << country
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if you can use the operator << that way.