# what method_function does in ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I am working in live project and understanding the existing code. 
   like

```
Module Rating
  def current_rating 
     # some code here
  end
end
```

And called this method in included class. 
How it works? 
Actually I know about module but not used much. Say I am beginner for `Module`

Comment: Yes I know about module.

Comment: Check this [module_function](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function) It will clear you to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

module_function

Module methods that are declared as *module_function* will create copies of themselves as private instance methods in the class that includes the Module:

check this link: [Hidden features of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby)

Comment: So what I understand here is that, to make it private.