# Unhandled exceptions in field initializations

Tags: java, exception, initialization

Does Java have any syntax for managing exceptions that might be thrown when declaring and initializing a class's member variable?

```
public class MyClass
{
  // Doesn't compile because constructor can throw IOException
  private static MyFileWriter x = new MyFileWriter("foo.txt"); 
  ...
}
```

Or do such initializations always have to be moved into a method where we can declare `throws IOException` or wrap the initialization in a try-catch block?

Comment: akf's answer is correct, but if you hate declaring new methods, you can also use static blocks to initialise your static variables; you can have try/catches within static blocks.

Comment: Lest others misread my last comment as an endorsement of the static-block approach: I prefer creating new methods. I just suggested an alternative for those who don't. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark the field as static. Does the recommendation still apply?

Comment: Or you can use non-static (i.e. instance) init blocks to initialise non-static fields. Try/catches work just as well. (Some consider this a "hidden feature", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java/47493#47493)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a static initialization block

```
public class MyClass
{
  private static MyFileWriter x;

  static {
    try {
      x = new MyFileWriter("foo.txt"); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logging_and _stuff_you_might_want_to_terminate_the_app_here_blah();
    } // end try-catch
  } // end static init block
  ...
}
```

Comment: you also have the option to throw a RuntimeException if you want to propagate after you do your handling.

Comment: Isn't this a problem if you have more than one class witha MyFileWriter member? You would have to rewrite your static block in every class.

Comment: Since it's a class member, doesn't that just come with the territory?

Comment: If the MyFileWriter has to be initialized for the class to function properly, then a RuntimeException should be thrown which will prevent the class from being loaded.  This would effectively render any code trying to use this class doomed to fail, which is probably the desired behaviour if it is crucial to the running of your application.  Logging without doing this will potentially make every call to MyClass methods fail instead.

Answer (score 3):

it is best practice to move those sorts of initializations to methods that can property handle exceptions.

Comment: agreed. I implemented a Factory method in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This construction is illegal, as you have discovered. Members whose constructors throw checked exceptions cannot be constructed except when in a context that allows exception handling, such as a constructor, an instance initializer, or (for a static member) a static initializer.

So this would be a legal way to do it:

```
public class MyClass {
    MyFileWriter x;
    {
        try {
            x = new MyFileWriter("foo.txt");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Legal, but rather ugly. I would prefer either initializing it in the constructor and declaring the exception there, or else making the user call a method to explicitly initialize it. But if the user must initialize it, you must then account in any dependent methods for the possibility of the object's being invalid.

If you are writing `MyClass` as a wrapper for `MyFileWriter`, I would say to do the initialization in the constructor. Otherwise, I would first question whether it is necessary to have a writer open during the object's entire lifetime. It may be possible to refactor this away.

**Edit:** When I was writing this, the "`static`" hadn't been added to the field. This changes things quite a bit: I now would like to know why on earth you want to have a writer open for the *classloader's* entire lifetime. How could it ever be closed?

Is this a home-grown logging system of some sort? If so, I'd encourage you to have a look at [`java.util.logging`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) or any of the many fine third-party logging frameworks around.

Answer (score 2):

An exception thrown from a static intialiser may indicate a design problem. Really you shouldn't be attempting to load files into statics. Also static should not, in general,  be mutable.

For instance, working back with JUnit 3.8.1 you could almost use it from an applet/WebStart, but it failed due to one static initialiser doing file access. The rest of the class involved was fitted the context fine, it's just this bit of static which did not fit the context and blew the whole framework away.

There are, some legitimate cases where an exception is thrown. If it's a case that the environment doesn't have a particular feature, say, because it's an old JDK, then you might want to substitute implementations, and there is nothing out of the ordinary. If the class really is borked, throw an unchecked exception rather than allowing a broken class to exist.

Depending on your preference and the problem at hand, there's two common ways to go around it: an explicit static initialiser and a static method. (I, and I think most people, prefer the former; I believe Josh Bloch prefers the latter.)

```
private static final Thing thing;

static {
    try {
        thing = new Thing();
    } catch (CheckedThingException exc) {
        throw new Error(exc);
    }
}
```

Or

```
private static final Thing thing = newThing();

private static Thing newThing() {
    try {
        return new Thing();
    } catch (CheckedThingException exc) {
        throw new Error(exc);
    }
}
```

Note: statics should be final (and generally immutable). Being final, correct single assignment is checked by your friendly compiler. Definite assignment means that it may catch broken exception handling - wrap and throw, do not print/log. Strangely, you can't user the class name to qualify the initialisation with the class name in the static initialiser (I'm sure there is a good reason for this).

Instance initialisers are similar, although you can make the constructor throw or you can put the initialiser within the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

If the class has only one constructor, I usually move such initializers into that constructor.

If the class has more than one constructor, I use an initialization block:

```
public class MyClass {
   private static MyFileWriter x;

   // initialization block start here
   {
       try {
          x = new MyFileWriter("..");
       } catch(Exception e) {
         // exception handling goes here
       }
   }

   public MyClass() { 
    // ctor #1
   }

   public MyClass(int n) { 
     // ctor #2
   }
}
```

The nice thing about an init. block is that it is "injected" into the beginning of every constructor. Thus, you don't need to duplicate the initializers.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a factory method:

```
  public class MyClass{
      private static MyFileWriter fileWriter = MyFileWriter.getFileWriter("foo.txt");

  }

  public class MyFileWriter {
     /*
      * Factory method. Opens files, etc etc 
      * @throws IOException.
      */
     public static MyFileWriter getFileWriter(String path) throws IOException{

        MyFileWriter writer  = new FileWriter();

       //stuff that can throw IOException here.

       return writer;
     }

   /*protected constructor*/
    protected MyFileWriter(){

     //build object here.

    } 
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, you have no exception handling in the call to the getFileWriter(), and to add it you will need to put in a static block.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to handle exception in field initializations. Let consider your case, where MyFileWriter constructor throws an exception. Consider this sample code for references.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class MyFileWriter {
    public MyFileWriter(String file) throws IOException{
         throw new IOException("welcome to [java-latte.blogpspot.in][1]");
    }
}
```

If we try to initialize file like this.....

```
public class ExceptionFields{
    MyFileWriter f = new MyFileWriter("Hello");

}
```

Compiler won't allow us to initialize this. Instead of doing initialization in the static block, you can do like this

Declare a default constructor that throws IOException

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class ExceptionFields{
    MyFileWriter f = new MyFileWriter("Hello");
    public ExceptionFields() throws IOException{    

    }    
}
```

This will initialize your MyFileWriter object.