# How to instantiate a collection in Java using Generics?

Tags: java

Whats the best way:

```
Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet();
```

Or

```
Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

None of the above?

Does it matter?

Comment: Check this question and accepted answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: In Java SE 7 (OUT NOW!) `Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet<>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter:

```
Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

See [the Java documentation on generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) for more information.

Comment: Just start using the untyped version...when you realize all of the annoying casts you have to do, you'll start using typed Collections!

Answer (score 3):

You should always initialize collection with generic type

```
Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

Otherwise you will get a warning

```
Type safety: The expression of type HashSet needs unchecked conversion 
to conform to Set <String>.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second is the best and safest way to proceed.

`Set<String> myStringSet = new HashSet();` will compile and give a `...uses unchecked or unsafe operations.` warning. This comes up in Java 5 and later, if you're using collections without generic type specifiers (`HashSet()` instead of `HashSet<String>()`).

Omitting the generic type specifier will disable the compiler from checking that you're using the `HashSet` in a type-safe way, using generics.