# What does <> mean for java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have a bit of code:

```
class MyClass<RCM> 
  private List<RCM> allPreExistingConfigsForCodes() {
    if(this.allCodesForThisType.size() == 0)
       return new ArrayList<RCM>(0);
```

IntelliJ is telling me I should replace `new ArrayList<RCM>` with `new ArrayList<>` what would that mean?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorials generics lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond):

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can replace the type arguments required to
>   invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type
>   arguments (`<>`) as long as the compiler can determine, or infer, the
>   type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets, `<>`, is
>   informally called *the diamond*. For example, you can create an instance
>   of `Box<Integer>` with the following statement:
>
> `Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();`

Answer (score 11):

Are you using Java 7? If so, it is trying to take advantage of the new "diamond notation."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#type-inference-instantiation