# Java, Collection constructor

Tags: java, collections, constructor, java-7

is there any difference between :

```
TreeMap<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

and

```
TreeMap<String, String> myMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Thanks!

Comment: you find some good point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same in java 7 where the diamond operator `<>` was introduced. In older versions of java the diamond operator will not work.

The diamond operator brings type inference to constructors. Type inference on generic methods is available in java 5 and higher. Prior to java 7, to create a generic class using the compiler's type inference you had to use generic factory methods like `static <K,T> Map<K,T> createMap()`.

Answer (score 1):

First one will only work in Java 7, the second one from Java 5+

Comment: Although note that since Generics are only used at compile-time, and don't exist in the byte-code, code using only Java-6 features plus the diamond operator, and compiled with a Java 7 compiler will run on a Java 6 JVM.

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all..! Its just a language construct. `<>` is newly introduced operator known as `diamond operator` from java 7.