# Java Generics syntax and calling a method on interface types such as List

Tags: java, list, generics, interface

What is reason behind supporting the syntax below on java 1.7

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
```

What flexibility does it provide?
If we wanted ints to be of a different type we would explicitly cast it and it would throw an error if the conversion could not be performed.

I am also not clear on how exactly does this work.Since List is an interface how are we able to call a method on it

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2);
ints.get(1);
```

Since return type of `asList()` is `static<T> List<T>` it's okay to access a field of a static interface without any class providing an implementation of it.But how are we able to access a method on such an interface
The collections library has a lot of them like `Collections.Sort()`
Who provides the implementation of these methods?

Comment: `return type of asList() is static List` ?

Comment: I think your wanted to write new ArrayList<Integer>() on first line.

Comment: @miNde I think he uses Java 7 with diamond syntax.

Comment: That's what he said but I didn't know you could put <> whithout precising the exact type. I think it would be better not to put it at all. Because in Java 6 you will get an error.

Comment: @miNde: wrong (at least for Java 7). Using `<>` asks the compiler to fill in the type, if he can. Using nothing at all uses a raw type and is discouraged.

Comment: @rAkesH: you have posted two completely separate questions, please post them as separate posts.

Comment: @FabianBarney ok thanks for giving me the syntax name, I didn't know that this was a new feature, I will search the web for it.

Comment: @Joaschim Sauer Then which one should i omit from this post?

Comment: @gefei As per the documentation.Yes it is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29

Comment: @rAkesH you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: @rAkesH I know the document says `static`. Do you know that this word means?

Comment: @JoachimSauer as you can read in the link I provided using <> whithout precising the type is not the same as providing it, but the same as precising the same type of the List object. So "List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>()" is like "List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>()", but not like "List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList()" because <> allows you to keep generics.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't format the text correctly so <T> went missing in the original post.Lion has corrected it now

Comment: @rAkesH Answering to "Then which one should i omit from this post?" : All 4 answerers answered your first question and only one (me) answered the second one. I think you could omit the second one.

Comment: @gefei Yes i know what static is but my knowing of that isn't much related to the answer.I had asked who provides the implementation for the interface..which has already been answered now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

Using

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

doesn't add any flexibility as they're exactly equivalent. The diamond (`<>`) indicates that we don't want the raw type but the obvious parameterized type.

Oracle describes it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) :

> In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the
>   constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):

It just makes the code a little less verbose, thus easier to read and maintain. This is probably more evident on Oracle's example :

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

compared to

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

**Question 2**

`Arrays.asList(1,2);` returns an object from a concrete class implementing the List interface.

In Java 1.6, it's an instance of the fixed-size `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` :

```
3354    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
3355        return new ArrayList<T>(a);
3356    }
```

but the important point is that an object always is of a concrete class implementing the methods its interfaces defines.

When you're doing `Collections.sort(`, you're not using the `Collection` interface but the [Collections](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java) class which contains this very concrete code :

```
132     public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
133         Object[] a = list.toArray();
134         Arrays.sort(a);
135         ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
136         for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
137             i.next();
138             i.set((T)a[j]);
139         }
140     }
```

Comment: In my opinion it is important to say that it is not an instance of the well-known `java.util.ArrayList` which is returned by `Arrays.asList()`. It is an instance from `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is a fixed-size implementation with private visibility modifier. Even better in my opinion is to not mention the used implementation at all.

Comment: @FabianBarney You're right. I edited. Thanks. I added the implementation to show there was a concrete class and that we weren't magically using the interface (I'm not really sure as how best to answer to the second question as I don't really get OP's problem, I wouldn't have answered if there weren't the first question).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I know objects can exist only for concrete types.I am interested in from does the implementation come.Could u also please mention which class provides the implementation of Sort() method on Collection interface?

Comment: When you're doing `Collections.sort(`, you're not using the `Collection` interface but the [Collections](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java) class.

Comment: I didn't observe it closely enough to see the difference of 1 letter.I was going to ask another stupid question that why don't ArrayList,HashSet ect have a Sort() method since Collection is the super interface of interfaces they implement but before that i noticed Collection interface doesn't have a Sort() method.Collections class happens to be contradiction to design by interfaces

Comment: @rAkesH ArrayList can hold instances of any type. To support `sort()` you must restrict to types that are comparable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of questions in your question.

Generics provide compile-time checking whereas casting errors are not discovered until runtime.

Your ints is an object that supports the List interface so it is valid to call methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

These are compile time checks, and are designed to ensure consistency, so implementations don't have to 'do' anything specific so long as they follow the rules laid down by the generics notation (e.g. for a method called with an object of type T, you only return something also of the same type T).

As has been pointed out, the diamond notation was brought in when it became clear that specifying a type in a constructor was unnecessarily verbose - the type can be clearly inferred (both by anyone reading the code, and by the compiler) from the target of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
```

Its Generics easy to understand and Iterate

```
for(Integer intObj : ints ) {}
```

instead of

```
Iterator itr = ints.iterator() ;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
   Integer intObj = (Integer) itr.next();
}
```

*Since return type of `Arrays.asList()` is static?*

Yes `java.util.Arrays` is an util class provides lots of utility methods.

*But how are we able to access a method on such an interface?*

Just view source code of `ArrayList` there you can find implementation methods from `List` interface.

*Who provides the implementation of these methods?*

The one who implement the interface like `List` `Set` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
```

is exactly the same as writing

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

It doesn't add flexibility, it just let you keep generics with your `ArrayList` whithout having to retype the type of the `ArrayList`, and so the `ArrayList` will not use raw type.

Some other thing is that writing this, you only get directly access to the `List` interface methods on your `ArrayList` object, event if these methods will have the behavior that is defined in the `ArrayList` class.

Answer (score 0):

> What flexibility does it provide?

It does not provide any flexibility; is just a syntactic sugaring. Kind of pointless since modern IDEs code completion already do that.

> Since return type of asList() is static List it's okay to access a field of a static interface without any class providing an implementation of it.But how are we able to access a method on such an interface The collections library has a lot of them like Collections.Sort() Who provides the implementation of these methods?

The return type of `asList()` is List; the type has nothing to do with the fact that the method is static. `Arrays` is a class, not an interface, and asList() method is implemented there; the JDK provides the implementation.