# string cannot be converted to component

Tags: java

i don't know what;s goin on, please help me master

```
private void btn_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        server_writer.write(cmb_server.getSelectedItem() + ":" +txt_chat.getText());
        server_writer.newLine();
        server_writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }

    list_chat.add("Me : " + txt_chat.getText()); // ERROR
    txt_chat.setText("");
}
```

*Note : App chatting with Jlist(Client-Server)

Comment: What is this : **dsfhskdjl**? and what is your question.

Comment: Hard to tell you on this input. What is list_chat?

Comment: @YoungMillie that's the "Oh no, SO has a minimum question length. But wait, I have an idea..."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list_chat` is a `JList`, the error tells you that you should add a `Component` instead of a `String` when using the `add()` method. See [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)).

I think you want to add elements to the list, the way it's explained in the answer to this question: [Adding elements to a JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214480/adding-elements-to-a-jlist) (but that's only a guess, you're question isn't clear).

What happens when you replace the line that causes the error with:

```
list_chat.addElement("Me : " + txt_chat.getText());
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Guessing**: list_chat is some sort of UI element that has a method `[add()][1]` that expects some JComponent as argument.

But this here:

```
"Me : " + txt_chat.getText()
```

results in a **String** object. A String is not a UI component.

And that is what the compiler is telling you. So the real answer here is: learn to read those compiler messages. They tell you exactly what the problem is ...