# Correctness of the implementation of the list

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a short question. For a very long time i implements ArrayList like this:

```
public ArrayList<Double> random = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

And no one correct me, so i thought it is good, but android studio underlines "Double" in 2nd ArrayList, but it works anyway

```
public ArrayList<Double> random = new ArrayList<>();
```

now Android studio do not show error, so what is the difference ?

Comment: Type is inferred from the declaration.  That should be obvious.  It doesn't work for static variables, though.  You should consider using List<Double> on the left hand side for the compile time type.

Comment: after java 7 there is no need to specify the type when you instantiate the object

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7 . And you can also specify just a `List` on the left side: `public List<Double> random = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: "For a very long time", you probably started learning about generics around Java 6, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357883/using-generics-on-right-hand-side-in-java-6

Comment: Both are correct, but the first is redundant, since you have already specified the type.

Answer (score 1):

It should be no problem by Java standards. Android prefers what Oracle calls a diamond operator for type inference.

You may read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html
There is also a long post about it on Stackoverflow: [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)