# Why does this not compile : List<List<String>> lss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

The below code :

```
List<List<String>> lss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

causes this compile time error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to List<List<String>>
```

to fix I change the code to :

```
List<ArrayList<String>> lss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Why is this error being thrown ? Is this because the generic type List in `List<List<String>>`  is instantiated and since List is an interface this is not possible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that type specifiers in generics do not (unless you tell it to) allow subclasses.  You have to match exactly.

Try either:

```
List<List<String>> lss = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

or:

```
List<? extends List<String>> lss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Exactly, everything in <> braces should match. Only class before <> braces can be subtype.

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

> Note: Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and
>   Integer),  `MyClass<A>` has no relationship to `MyClass<B>`, regardless of
>   whether or not  A and B are related. The common parent of `MyClass<A>`
>   and `MyClass<B>` is Object.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Same reason

```
List<List> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

wont work.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834145/whats-the-use-of-saying-extends-someobject-instead-of-someobject/17834223#17834223) question for more details.