# Isn't List<List<String>> same as List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

```
public List<Object> query(){

        List<Object> listToReturn = new ArrayList<Object>();  
        List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<List<String>> listOfListOfString = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        listOfListOfString.add(listOfString);
        listToReturn.add(listOfListOfString);

        return listToReturn;
    }
```

Instead of above method if I write :

```
public List<Object> query(){

        List<Object> listToReturn = new ArrayList<Object>();    
        List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<List<String>> listOfListOfString = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        listOfListOfString.add(listOfString);

        return listOfListOfString;

    }
```

I get a compile-time error, `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<List<String>>> to List<Object>`

I am a bit confused.

Comment: +1: Good question. I don't know why. Probably somewhere described in the JLS.

Comment: concrete parameterized type are different! http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could do that, the caller, which gets a `List<Object>`, would be able to add any kind of Object to the list, although it's been declared as a `List<List<String>>`. It would thus ruin the type-safety of the list:

```
List<List<String>> listOfListOfString = ...;
List<Object> listOfObjects = listOfListOfString;
listOfObjects.add(new Banana()); 
// now your list of lists of strings contains a banana: oops!
```

You can do the following, however, which would prevent the caller from adding anything to the list though:

```
List<?> query() { // equivalent of List<? extends Object>
    ...
    return listOfListOfString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> > **Is `List<Object>` a supertype of `List<String>`?**
> >
> > No, different instantiations of the same generic type for different concrete type arguments have no type relationship.
> >     [FAQ102](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ102)

The error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<List<String>>> to List<Object>` means that both objects has different *concrete parameterized type*.

> > **What is a concrete parameterized type?**
> >
> > An instantiation of a generic type where all type arguments are concrete types rather than wildcards. 
> >     [FAQ101](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ101)

More:

- [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java)
- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)
- [Why does this not compile : List<List<String>> lss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702635/why-does-this-not-compile-listliststring-lss-new-arraylistarrayliststr?rq=1)

Source: [Java Generics FAQs - Generic And Parameterized Types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)