# How to create List<List<T>> in java?

Tags: java, collections

Why list1 is valid way of instantiation but not list2?

```
List<List<T>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
List<List<T>> list2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
```

I want to create a list of type list i.e.

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
```

Comment: Also exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702635/why-does-this-not-compile-listliststring-lss-new-arraylistarrayliststr

Comment: Google diamond operator, it will make the initialization simple.