# Method in the type Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends Object> is not applicable

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have the following `JAVA` method implemented due a interface:

```
public String importDocument(ImportSource source, Map<String, ? extends Object> paramMap);
```

When i try to do following, i get an compile warning.
Snippet:

```
paramMap.put("Key", "Value");
```

Error:

> The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
? extends Object
```

You are using generic wildcard. You cannot perform add operation as class type is not determinate. You cannot add/put anything(except null).

For more details on using wildcard you can refer oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
```

Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add objects to it. The `add()` method takes arguments of `type E`, the element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is `?`, it stands for some `unknown type`. Any parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. `The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type`.

Comment: Does it mean, that if i need to add a value to the params, i must create a new map with all values and use this instead?

Comment: If you want to add params then dont use wildcard use `Map<String,Object>` instead.

Comment: Anyway `? extends Object` makes no sense as every class is eligible as the argument.

Comment: I can't change it, is a well defined interface which i must use as it is. However i don't really get it. What is the difference between `Map<String, ?>` and `Map<String, ? extends Something>`

Comment: @Emaborsa you may want to see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834145/whats-the-use-of-saying-extends-someobject-instead-of-someobject/17834223#17834223).

Comment: Or `<String, T extends Object>` would also solve it (if `T` is a type param for the function).