# Integer extends Number but can't operate on <? extends Number> with Integer

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends

Integer extends Number so why do I get the error at the bottom?

```
interface Predicate<T> {
   public abstract boolean check(T t);
}

Predicate<? extends Number> predUpper = null;

predUpper.check(new Integer(73));
```

Error: The method check(capture#6-of ? extends Number) in the type Predicate is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

I have read: [Method in the type Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends Object> is not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041142/method-in-the-type-mapstring-capture1-of-extends-object-is-not-applicable) and [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `Predicate` will *consume* the `Integer`, you should do:

```
Predicate<? super Integer> predUpper //Solution 1
```

or just:

```
Predicate<Number> predUpper //Solution 2
```

There's difference, however, in these approaches:

- The type-parameter `<? super Integer` from "Solition 1" represents a **whole family** of super-types of `Integer` (including `Integer`).
- The type-parameter `<Number>` from "Solution 2" represents a sub-class of the `Number` interface. Since `Integer` is such, it's applicable here.

More info:

- [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)