# updating a method testMethod(Map<String, ?> settings) in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a method, where I am trying to modify the value of one key of a map.

I cannot change the signature of the map .

```
public void testMethod(Map<String, ?> settings) {

    this.xyzkey = (String) settings.get(xyzkey);

    settings.put("xyzkey" ,settings.get(xyzkey)+"test"));

}
```

Now when I want to get a specific key from the map and modify its values
I am getting Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:'java.lang.String',required:'?'.

Please suggest any way o update the key's value .

Answer (score 0):

You try get the value by the key `xyzkey` (your class' member) and put the changed value to the key `"xyzkey"` (a string). So you need to change your `get` to `get("xyzkey")` or your `put` to `put(xyzkey, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`public void testMethod(Map<String, ?> settings) {`

You are using generics wildcards here.
In this method your input type for argument is not defined, so you can add anything to the map(**except null**).

Found well described answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041142/method-in-the-type-mapstring-capture1-of-extends-object-is-not-applicable).

Comment: @StefanWarminski while the code didn´t have it, the question title somewhat implies it was just left out here (as the title did have it).

Comment: Yeah, just checked my edit. But I just selected the code and used CTRL+k for code formatting. Didn't change anything else.

Comment: @StefanWarminski I asked the question(how generics was added) on meta and people on SO have answer to everything. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349298/how-does-code-formatting-works