# How to add an entry with an Integer value into Map<String, ?>

Tags: java, generics, collections, unbounded-wildcard

I have to place an integer value into the map below.

```
Map<String,?> map
map.put("key",2000);
```

When I run the above code I'm getting the following error:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
```

Comment: can't you declare it as Map<String,Integer> map

Comment: Use `Map<String, Object>` if you want to be able to put any kind of objects into the map.

Comment: I'm getting this map as argument, I cant change it.

Comment: I need to override for one specific key.

Comment: The actual map could be a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` and then your `put` cannot be done. That is the portent of the error message you got. A `Map<String, ?>` cannot be used with `put`. BAD LUCK. `Map<String, Object>` would have worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method in the type Map<String,capture#1-of ? extends Object> is not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041142/method-in-the-type-mapstring-capture1-of-extends-object-is-not-applicable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Unbounded**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) generic collections (`Collection<?>`) are **not writable**. Let's explore why.

#### Unknown type - <?>

A question mark in angle brackets `<?>` is called the **unknown type**. For the compiler, that means that the *actual type* can't be predicted and at runtime it could appear to be pretty match anything: an `Object`, a `String`, a `Cat`. Therefore, everything that you retrieve from the **unbounded collection** will be treated as an `Object`:

```
Collection<?> items = new ArrayList<>();
Object item = items.iterator().next(); // this assignment is safe and will compile
```

But *don't confuse* an *unbounded collection* `Collection<?>` with a *collection of objects* `Collection<Object>`. They are ***incompatible***.

`Collection<Object>` has **invariant behavior**, i.e. it expects only another *collection* of type `Object` to be assigned to it. Meanwhile, we can assign a collection of ***any*** type to `Collection<?>`.

```
Collection<?> items = new ArrayList<String>();         // OK

Collection<Object> objects1 = items;                   // that will not compile
Collection<Object> objects2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // that will not compile
Collection<Object> objects3 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // OK - compiler will not complain here
```

So, **unknown type** could be represented by anything that **extends** `Object`. And you might think about `Collection<?>` as if it is a [**upper-bounded**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) collection `Collection<? extends Object>`. They are absolutely ***compatible***.

```
Collection<?> items = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<? extends Object> upperBounded = items; // no issues
items = upperBounded;                              // no issues
```

#### Modifying an unbounded collection

Wild-cards like `<?>` or `<? extends Object>` are ***not actual types***. They are just a way to tell the compiler that we don't know what the *type* will be at runtime.

Then what will be the *actual type* of `Collection<?>` ?

Since it's already clear that *unknown type* (`<?>`) implies that it could be *any type* that extends `Object`, hence under the hood of a `Collection<?>` could appear an `ArrayList<Object>`, an `ArrayList<String>`, a `HashSet<BigDecimal>`, etc.

***Remainder***: parameterized collection that will appear in the guise of `Collection<?>` at runtime is **invariant**, which means that `ArrayList<String>` is expected to contain only `String`s and  `HashSet<BigDecimal>` is expected to store only instances of `BigDecimal`. But that there's no way to ensure that at runtime because during the compilation generic parameters [*get erased*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).  Therefore, the only way to provide type-safety while utilizing unbounded generic collection is to disallow to add anything into it.

For example, since it's *illegal* to add an `Integer` or an `Object` into an `ArrayList<String>`, or to add an instance of `String` into a `HashSet<BigDecimal>` compiler will *prevent* any attempt to *add* anything to the `Collection<?>`. Because there's no type compatible with the **unknown type**.

There's only one exception, `null` is a valid value for any type of object, and therefore it could be added into an *unbounded* as well as into an *upper-bounded* collection.

```
Collection<?> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(null);
System.out.println(items);
items.remove(null);
System.out.println(items.isEmpty());
```

Will give an *output*:

```
[null]  -  null-element was successfuly added
true    -  i.e. isEmpty
```

***Note*:** that there are ***no*** restrictions on *removal* of elements for both *unbounded* and *upper-bounded* collections.

#### Alternatives

Hence, there's ***no way*** to add new entries to the **unbounded map** you can either copy its entries one by one performing an `instanceOf` check into the regular generic map `Map<String, Integer>` get rid of generics at all by assign the map to a variable of **row type**, and then add *type-casts* manually when need to retrieve a *value* like in Java 1.4.

That how you can copy the contents of **unbounded map** to a **regular** and utilize the advantages of generics.

```
Map<String, ?> unboundedMap = new HashMap<>()

Map<String, Integer> writableMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: unboundedMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
        writableMap.put(entry.getKey(), (Integer) entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

The same thing by using the Stream API

```
Map<String, Integer> writableMap =
       unboundedMap.entrySet().stream()
                   .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Integer)
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                             entry -> (Integer) entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign many things to a a variable of type `Map<String, ?>` . For example:

```
Map<String, ?> map;

map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // works
map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // works
map = new HashMap<String, Number>(); // works
map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // works
```

That all works. So, let's say that `map = new HashMap<String, String>()` was assigned to it. And then you attempt to run `.put("key", 2000);` on it.

That, obviously, makes no sense. Hence why that code doesn't compile.

I'm assuming that your eyeballs and human brain looked at this code and determined that the `map` you have there couldn't possibly be pointing at anything other than either a `Map<String, Object>` or a `Map<String, Number>` or a `Map<String, Integer>` or even a `Map<String, Serializable>` - types for which `.put("key", 2000)` would be sensible.

But that's not how java works. Part of the point of types is to restrict yourself and give yourself the freedom to assign other stuff later.

It is *exactly* analogous to this:

```
Object x = "hello";
x.toLowerCase();
```

The above **does not compile**: The `Object` type doesn't have a `toLowerCase()` method. Yes, yes, our eyeballs and brain look at this and go: That's stupid, of course it does! Look, `x` is *clearly* pointing at a string!

But in such cases, just.. write `String x = "hello"`.

So, the same applies for your scenario. Just write `Map<String, Integer>` instead.

### Unfortunately....

sometimes you have dynamic code that wants to check what a thing is and act accordingly. For example:

```
void foo(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof String s) return s.toLowerCase();
  throw new SomeException();
}
```

But you can't do that for generics - generics cannot be `instanceof` checked. You can't do something like: *IF* the object my `map` variable is pointing at has `Integer` as value type (or any supertype of Integer), then do `map.put("key", 2000)`, otherwise don't.

That's just not how generics works in java. There is simply no way to do this.

The only thing you can do is just decree it. Write code that works fine if it is true, but messes everything up if it is not true: You can FORCIBLY run `.put("key", 2000)` on the map, which will put that in the map, and if that is a map declared as, say, `Map<String, String>`, then any code that interacts with this map will start throwing `ClassCastExceptions` left and right even though they never cast anything. Because you shoved an integer into a map of strings.

Hence why the compiler yells at when you force this, and why you shouldn't be doing this. The only point of generics is to make your programming life easier, to clarify APIs, and to catch bugs, and you're.. doing the opposite of it by forcing it. But, hey, if you really want to do this (highly unlikely):

```
void example(Map<String, ?> map) {
  Map forceIt = map; // raw assignment
  forceIt.put("key", 2000); // compiles
}
```

The above compiles and does what you asked for - but will warn you that this is a very bad idea.

of (o instanceof String) return ((String) o).toLowerCase();

Answer (score 1):

```
        Map<String, Integer> map = new Map<String, Integer>;
        map.put("key",2000);
```

Comment: I'm getting this map as argument, I cant change it. I'm in a situation to change value for one key.