# Difference between a list of object types and a list of objects extending a type

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, interface, extends

I often encounter situations like:

```
List<Fooable> fooList;
```

vs

```
List<? extends Fooable> fooList;
```

What is the difference between these two? Or is there a name for this / pre-existing link where this difference is described? I can't Google this concept because I don't know what it's called or how else you'd describe this.

Does it matter if Fooable is an interface? A concrete class? An abstract class? Does this only apply to classes that extend and/or implement something?

Comment: I believe that is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: Or here. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/what-is-the-difference-between-extends-foo-and-foo

Comment: As for the name of that construct, it is called "upper bounded wildcard", see for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Comment: @cricket_007, the proposed duplicate doesn't really answer OP's question. To me, it's clear that this question is about whether types `<Fooable>` and `<? extends Fooable>` are interchangeable, and not about bounded wildcards in general.

Comment: @user140547 This was helpful, in particular this sentence: `The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number> because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses.`

Comment: So `List<Animal>` literally means the list contains `Animal` objects -- not `Cats` or `Dogs`, but literally `Animals`. If I wanted a list including `Cats` and `Dogs` I'd have `List<? extends Animal>` assuming we have `Cat extends Animal` or `Dog extends Animal`. Does this matter whether `Cat` is extending or implementing `Animal`?

Comment: I think if there was a concrete example that you've ran into the differences might become more apparent. And no that's not what it means. A list of Animals (`List<Animal>`) can indeed hold Cats and Dogs. I would try some code and observe the uses.

Comment: Actually, the linked question on Programmers SO does seem like a duplicate.

Comment: That's not what the Java link says though? `the former matches a list of type Number only`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you're understanding it. I don't want to add an answer when the first link is so well done but you have nearly an opposite understanding of what is true. Quickly write those classes (yes Animal can be an interface) and then try to add some animals to the two types of lists you have. It's not going to behave as you say.

Comment: I am literally going from what the Java link says. How is my understanding the opposite? Is the Java link wrong?

Comment: It's opposite because you're saying `List<Animal>` must *not* contain Cats or Dogs but that's not true; that's basic polymorphic behavior and makes sense since Cats and Dogs *are* Animals.

Comment: Makes sense to me intuitively, but if `List<Animal>` can contain Cats and Dogs, what about `List<? extends Animal>`? Does that list also contain Cats and Dogs? If so, how are the lists different in what they can do?

Comment: Read the newly added answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if there is no duplicate...

A `List<Animal>` *can* contain `Cat`s and `Dog`s. You can add Cats and Dogs to the list. It does not mean it can only contain `Animal`s.

But if you have a method `foo(List<Animal> foo)`, you can not pass a `List<Cat>` to it. But you can add `Cat`s, `Dog`s or `Animal`s to the passed `List<Animal>`.

If you have a `foo(List<? extends Animal> foo)`, you can pass a `List<Animal>`,`List<Dog>`, and `List<Cat>` to it and read from it, i.e. you can access `Animal`s methods.

But since any List of subtype of `Animal` may be passed to it (you don't know which type, it may be an  `Animal`, a `Cat` or a `Dog`, or some totally different `Animal`, you cannot add any elements (except `null`) to it.

Comment: Is it an arbitrary restriction? I would have assumed that `foo(List<Animal> foo)` would accept `List<Cat>` since Cat is an Animal

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: So basically, the answer is that Java's generics work in a very counter-intuitive way.

Comment: Also, I found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834145/whats-the-use-of-saying-extends-someobject-instead-of-someobject/17834223).