# Java API class having a method with a meaningless type wildcard

Tags: java, generics

In Java 8, the class `java.util.Optional` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)) class offers functionality of the ["Maybe" Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#The_Maybe_monad) or the [Option Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type).

More directly:

> *public final class java.util.Optional<T> extends Object*
>
> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a
>   value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return
>   the value.

[One of the methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is:

> *<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)*
>
> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if
>   the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result.

The question is simply why does `map()` use a type wildcard on the `U` type.

My understanding of type wildcarding is simply that:

[image]

`? super T` designates some type from the set of classes given by the subclassing path from `Object` to `T` (both `Object` and `T` included) union the set of interfaces found on any subinterfacing path pulled in "as a sidedish" via `implements`.

And `? extends U` simply designates some type from the set of classes that extend `U` (`U`included).

So one could just write:

> *<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,U> mapper)*

without loss of information.

Or not?

Comment: Pretty close question (if not identical): [Whats the use of saying <? extends SomeObject> instead of <SomeObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834145/whats-the-use-of-saying-extends-someobject-instead-of-someobject/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite.

A `Function<? super T, U>` is not the same as a `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`.

For example, I could still get an `Optional<CharSequence>`, even if I passed a `Function<Object, String>` to the method. If the method was defined as `<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, U> mapper)`, then this would not be possible.

That is because generics are invariant: `<T>` is not the same as `<? extends T>`. That's a design decision implemented in the Java language.

Let's see how [Jon Skeet explains what would happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/) if generics would not be invariant:

```
class Animal { }

class Dog extends Animal { }

class Cat extends Animal { }
```

```java
public void ouch() {
    List<Dog> dogs = Arrays.asList(new Dog(), new Dog());
    List<Animal> animals;
    // This would be legal, right? Because a list of dogs is a list of animals.
    List<Animal> animals = dogs;
    // This would be legal, right? Because a cat could be added to a
    // list of animals, because a cat is an animal.
    animals.add(new Cat());
    // Unfortunately, we have a confused cat.
}
```

---

Although I'm not entirely sure what you mean in your comments, I'll try to elaborate.

If you have full control over the `Function` you provide, it doesn't matter whether the method's signature is `Function<? super T, U>` or `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`, you'll just adapt your `Function` accordingly. But the authors of the method probably wanted the method to be **as flexible as possible**, allowing one to provide a `Function` with its second parameter to be also a subclass of `U`, instead of only `U` itself. Actually you widen its lower bound from `U` to a certain subtype of `U`.

> *So the function should really read `<U> Optional<? the-most-general-but-fixed-supertype-of U> map(Function<? super T, U> mapper)` but expressing it that way would be awkward.*

I would be indeed awkward. In addition, there is a difference between your proposed notation and the actual method signature of `map()`, which involve implications of **lower bounds** and **upper bounds**.

Read more:

- [A picture explaining the principle "Producer Extends Consumer Super"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/)
- [What is the use of saying `<? extends SomeObject>` instead of `<SomeObject>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17834145/)
- [Upper and lower bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19795709/)

Comment: `Optional.map` signature is a good example of [Producer Extends Consumer Super](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=bloch+effective+java+pecs+mnemonic&source=bl&ots=yYKnPjt-P-&sig=JGT8qexAAldJ5xYPepbBQ5uude0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Cb3GUv-sNIuK5ATM7oD4Dw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bloch%20effective%20java%20pecs%20mnemonic&f=false) principle

Comment: Let me think about this for a minute. _Invariant_ means that generic types are not comparable or in any hierarchical relationship, right? Because that would open a can of worms or run-time type information carry & checks. Whereas using wildcards allows us to express an additional constraint holding between related types.

Comment: It feel like it's a question of intent. We want to express the following: "map is a function that will return `Optional<U>` where `U` is a most generic type that still makes sense here (e.g. `CharSequence`, and because we want to avoid writing type-specific code for example), and it accepts a `mapper` from which we just require that it return some subtype of `U`. The point being that `mapper`s may already exist and we want to accomodate them all while coding `map()` for them. As opposed to thinking the other way: `map()` already exists and we code the `mapper`s that we give it...

Comment: ...in which case the restrictive `<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,U> mapper)` would be fine. So the function should really read `<U> Optional<? the-most-general-but-fixed-supertype-of U> map(Function<? super T,U> mapper)` but expressing it that way would be awkward.

Comment: I will accept this as answer because it helped, though its was not exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: I tried to elaborate on the things you commented, I updated my post.