# Cast Set of some object type to Set of interface type which implement

Tags: java, oop, interface, pojo

is possible in some elegant way cast Set of Foo objects cast into Set of IFoo?

I need call method like this:

```
public Set<Bar> doSomething(Set<IFoo>) { ... }
```

with Set like this:

```
private Set<Foo> foos;
```

where Foo has definition is this:

```
public class Foo implements IFoo { ... }
```

When I tried `doSomething(Set<IFoo> foos)` I got error **Inconvertible type**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17834223/34397

Comment: `doSomething(new HashSet<>(foos));`

Comment: you could do doSomething(Set<? extends IFoo>)