# Initialisation of Generic List of Generic List

Tags: java, list, initialization

Why can I not declare a List of Lists like this?

```
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

An ArrayList is of type List so I presumed that the above code would be valid.

This is valid though:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> b = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

The inner list has to be declared as ArrayList.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing your generics. The way to do what you want is

```
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

By using `ArrayList` within the generic parameter, you're narrowing the scope of the object from `List` to `ArrayList`, thereby changing the generic signature. By using `ArrayList` outside the generic, you're still conformant; you're specifying which implementation of `List` you want to use, and that the objects it will hold are of type `List<Object>`, exactly as the left hand side states.

To see why this is important, consider this list:

```
// Invalid declaration, but pretend it is valid
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
a.add(new ArrayList<Object>()); // valid
a.add(new LinkedList<Object>()); // not valid because it's not an ArrayList; 
                                 // but according to the left side, it is valid!
```

Of course, the best method is to use Java 7's [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7):

```
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as much a problem with the inner list as it is the problem of the generic parameter. As long as the generic parameter is the same (i.e. `ArrayList<Object>`) the initialization succeeds. Otherwise, Java does not let you make an assignment, because the compiler cannot guarantee type safety.

Imagine that this is possible:

```
// Let's pretend this compiles:
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Now the following must be valid:

```
a.add(new LinkedList<Object>());
```

However, this is invalid, because the object is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s, so inserting a linked list into it is clearly invalid.

You can do this, however:

```
List<List<Object>> a = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

This should be good enough to program to the interface.