# Diamond Generic and Legacy in Java

Tags: java, generics

In Collections I've found the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();
```

I really can't find any reason to use:

```
new EmptyList<>()
```

here instead of:

```
new EmptyList()
```

as it would be for java < 1.7.

Is there any difference between this approach?

Comment: i couldn't find EmptyList in java1.7

Comment: @ByteCode that's an internal class used inside Collections.

Comment: @ByteCode You'll find it at line 3185, in `Collections`'s source.

Comment: No, no difference in that case, except that you'll get a warning when you don't specify the generic type parameter when instantiating a generic type.

Comment: isnot2bad and afsantos  thanks....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Are there any cases when the difference will take place?

Comment: It makes no difference - as a side note, you should use `Collections.emptyList()` instead to avoid the unchecked conversion warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned only about <> operator then you should see [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7).

Regarding EMPTY_LIST:
Either you do :

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
List list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

OR Something like:

```
List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
```

The reason to use <> operator is maintaining compile time checking for raw types. The above links describes that well.

Comment: I think he knows what's the point of diamond operator. He is just asking what's the point behind it in the scenario he has shown.