# Difference in List<Integer> l = new ArrayList() and List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<integer>()

Tags: java, generics

What is difference in following two declarations

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList(); //and 

List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**If not** then why in java 7 `dimond operator` ie `<>` is introduced to avoid type writing at right side of `'='` or at object creation side.

Comment: Dublicate question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: @nbroos What you are describing is the type argument on the variable type declaration, not on the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this example

```
List<Float> f = new ArrayList();     // this list hold(s) Float(s).
f.add(2.0f);
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList(f);  // Oh no.... 
l.add(1);
System.out.println(l);
```

If I run the above I get

```
[2.0, 1]
```

If I used the diamond operator, I would get a compiler error. Does that help?
At run-time every Collection holds java.lang.Ojbect(s) due to type erasure, this is compile time type checking only.

Answer (score 2):

This will causes the `[unchecked] warning`:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
```

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167148/2675669)

Comment: ohh..my netbeans not showing that warning.How to do setting in netbeans to enable to show warnings

Comment: go to Tools > Options > Editor > Hints select java under there is ..