# Instantiating a class which has generic params?

Tags: java, generics

I have below class created.

```
public class SomeRequest<B extends Billing,E extends Employee, L extends Level>{


B billing;


E employee;

Class<L> level;

public void process(HashMap<String, Object> input){

        this.billing = (B)data.get("billing");
    this.employee= (E)data.get("employee");
    this.level = (Class<L>)data.get("level");

         //Some logic

  }

}
```

In above class `Employee`, `Billing` and `Level` are Java POJOs.

Now how can i instantiate above `SomeRequest` class?

Thanks!

Comment: `SomeRequest<Billing, Employee, Level> someRequest = new SomeRequest<Billing, Employee, Level>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3269829 you should not use HashMap for contain data of different types. You can add custom container, i.e. a class with three field:

```
class Container<B extends Billing,E extends Employee, L extends Level> {

    B billing;

    E employee;

    L level;

    public Container(B b, E e, L l) {
        billing = b;
        employee = e;
        level = l;
    }

    // ... getters only!
}
```

The process() method will have next signature:

```
 public void process(Container<B, E, L> input)
```

In the process() method you can:

```
SomeRequest<Billing,Employee,Level> instance = new SomeRequest<>();
instance.setBilling(container.getBilling());
instance.setEmployee(container.getEmployee());
instance.setLevel(container.getLevel());
```

or

```
SomeRequest<Billing,Employee,Level> instance = new SomeRequest<>(container.getBilling(), container.getEmployee(), container.getLevel());
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that `SomeRequest` class has a no-arg constructor*

In Java 7 using the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

```
SomeRequest<Billing,Employee,Level> instance = new SomeRequest<>();
```

In Java 6 or 5

```
SomeRequest<Billing,Employee,Level> instance = new SomeRequest<Billing,Employee,Level>();
```

Comment: Narendra, thanks for your answer. I just edited my question and am using Java7.

Comment: @user3269829 Glad to help. You should certainly use first option if you are using Java 7.

Comment: Narendra, in the Hashmap, i have to pass two objects and one class type right? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. I didn't get what you said.

Comment: In the question i have a method which takes hash map as an input. In hash map i have to set two objects and one class type right?

Comment: Oh and looking at your profile seems that you are new to stackoverflow. Once you are satisfied with an answer you should accept the best answer as accepted. Read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more

Comment: sure Narendra..i will accept it...could you please look into my process() which takes hash map as an input?

Comment: That should be a separate post and that too in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Asking such questions about review are off topic at stackoverflow. Again something that can be learnt from FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 5 or 6 you can use factory method as replacement for constructor with generics. In Java 5 or 6 type inference work fine on methods but not on constructors. You can write something like:

```
public class SomeRequest<B extends Billing,E extends Employee, L extends Level>{
   private SomeRequest(B billing, E employee, L level) {
       // ...
   }

   public static <B,E,L> with(B billing, E employee, L level) {
        return new SomeRequest<B, E, L>(billing, employee, level);
   }
}
```

Now you should't write `new SomeRequest(billing, employee, level)`, you can write simple `SomeRequest.with(billing, employee, level)`.

Oh, sorry, I asked before have seen your comment about Java 7.

Comment: OP is using Java 7. Good point though. That's static method type reference.

Comment: I asked before @user3269829 added info about Java 7.

Comment: samolisov, can you please take a look at process() method in my question?

Comment: Please replace your HashMap on custom class (i.e. Container) and get fields from this class, HashMap, HashSet and others collections with generics is unappropriated for contain different types.