# Java, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException caused due to not initializing an object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, initialization

Help me with this, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" 
thanks

```
private List< PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos;
private List< PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos;

//-------------------------------

 int cantidad = this.posibles_terrenos.size(); 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < cantidad ; i++)
        {
            if(this.posibles_terrenos.get(i).get_validez() == true)
            {
                this.terrenos_validos.add(this.posibles_terrenos.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception).

Comment: Make sure you have `posibles_terrenos = new ...` and same for `terrenos_validos` somewhere before executing the line throwing exceptiion

Comment: And then look at the exception message and stack trace, which will tell you exactly which line of which file it occurred on and what you were doing at the time.

Comment: You have to make sure posibles_terrenos and terrenos_validos are correctly initialized.

Comment: private List< PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos;
private List< PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos;

it's defined next to " public class Controlador { "

Comment: Lists are objects in Java and you need to initialize them as many commenters have pointed out. You cannot do something (in your case .get(i).get_validez()) on object members without initializing them.

Comment: :D initialized in in the constructor
thanks

Comment: Then it´s not enough information to determine the origin of the error. Could you post some more of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *[declared](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20declared%20java)* these variables

```
private List< PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos;
private List< PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos;
```

but you have not *[initialized](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20initialize%20java)* them. You need to do something along the lines of

```
private List< PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos = new ArrayList<PosibleTerreno>();
private List< PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos = new ArrayList<PosibleTerreno>();
```

Otherwise, both lists are `null`, and attempting to reference any of their functions...doesn't even make sense, because there's no "their" there. They're *nothing*. So attempting this

```
int cantidad = this.posibles_terrenos.size();
```

will obviously result in a `NullPointerException`.

(+1 for three homophones in a row.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your `List(s)`, you might use a [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and/or a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) perhaps with -

```
private List<PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos = new ArrayList<PosibleTerreno>();
private List<PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos = new LinkedList<PosibleTerreno>();
```

With Java 7 and above, you can also use the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/2970947) like so -

```
private List<PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos = new ArrayList<>();
private List<PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

do this before executing the line throwing the exception.

```
private List< PosibleTerreno> posibles_terrenos = new ArrayList<PosibleTerreno>();
private List< PosibleTerreno> terrenos_validos = new ArrayList<PosibleTerreno>();
```