# How to create a map instance variable

Tags: java, dictionary, bluej

I've been trying to create a class that will model a scenario I've come up with. It will involve a map with string keys and values.

I need to create an instance variable used to reference the map object, and a constructor that creates the empty map and assigns it to the map instance variable.

I've been messing around with map objects but not creating a class using them, and I've hit a mental block!

What's the proper way to actually get a map object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TheClass {    

  private Map<String, String> theMap;

  public TheClass() {
    theMap = new HashMap<>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Demo {

    Map<String,String> map = null;

    public Demo()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize it with values, directly as a class member?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HashMap which is Map implementation you can do it like that:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

or

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

in Java 7.

You can also use other implementations like TreeMap.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HashMap which is an implementation of Map
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("key1", "Value1");
map.put("Key2", "Value2");
```

Comment: Java 7 supports the `<>` operator.

Comment: @LutzHorn Thanks. I never knew

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7