# Java <> operator description

Tags: java, operators

I've been given some java code which contains a <> operator. What is the function of this operator?.

```
if(x <> 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I've never seen it before and its not on the operators page of http://docs.oracle.com/
I'd have put it down to a typo but it shows up twice in the same piece of code.

Comment: That would not compile.

Comment: @markubik no in Java operator you describe would look like `!=`, not `<>`.

Comment: You've been given some wrong java code. There's no `<>` operator in Java.

Comment: Thanks. The code was given to me by a guy with a PHD, hence I thought it was just something I didn't know about.

Comment: maybe its from another language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely an error the programmer missed, bc some ide's will automatically add the greater than sign when you type the less than sign first.

e.g. eclipse will convert `<` to `<>`, you just got to remember to delete the second operand.

this operator `<>` is actually a not equal to (`!=`) operator in other languages, like sql for example.

lastly like everybody else said, this `<>` expression is for generics in java.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x <> 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This is not valid operator<sup>1</sup> in Java<sup>2</sup>. So it won't compile. If you want to use non-equal operator you have to use `!=` operator:

```
if (x != 0) { // this is valid use in Java
    doSomething();
}
```

Here you can find list of [all valid operators in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

*Example of usage <> symbol in generics:*

A generic class is defined with the following format: `class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { ... }`

Here, you can see "your symbol":

> The type parameter section, delimited by **angle brackets (<>)**, follows
>   the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type
>   variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.

For more information you need to have look at [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Hope this will make things clearer.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Symbol `<>` is used in Java only while instantiating generic type.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Symbol `<>` is valid for example in SQL language. Look at [SQL operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-operators.htm).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid Java code, it will cause a compilation error:

```
if (x <> 0)
```

The correct way to express the above is:

```
if (x != 0)
```

The only part where the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) is allowed is when instantiating a generic type, and only since Java 7. For instance:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```