# HashMap initialization

Tags: java

If I write

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
```

as opposed to

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or as opposed to

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

will the 1st one be unsafe in any way?

Comment: The latter two are equivalent; not too sure about the first one but I believe it makes things a little messy because of the lack of generics.

Comment: I don't know about 'unsafe' but for the second variation, you might want to read [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel Yes, the point of my question is what's bad with the 1st one

Comment: You should see the same bytecode generated for all three.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second is just an abbreviation of the third alternative.

The first way can cause problems if you use a different constructor, because it ignores generics.

For instance, the following compiles:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> intMap = ...;
Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap(intMap);
```

It will even execute without errors because there are no generic checks at runtime. But if `intMap` contained data and you access it from `strMap` (eg., by iterating over keys), you will get a runtime exception.

Such a bug would be very hard to track because the exception might occur far away from the offending line.

So, in your particular case it wouldn't cause problems, but if you make this a habit you will run into problems eventually. Furthermore, you will get compiler warnings which you would have to suppress or ignore, both things that should be avoided.

Answer (score -4):

Alex,

It is not likely "unsafe", but the extra specificity of the third example provides the greatest degree of typesafe protection from the runtime.

I would recommend using the interface with generics to instantiate:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Comment: Why is this better than `new HashMap<>()`? What protection does it offer?

Comment: Slightly misleading; the second and third alternatives are *exactly* equal. The "extra specificity" that you talk about is actually extra *verbosity*