# What kind of objects can be added in List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the type inference and the use of diamond operator.

Assuming that `RaceCar` is a subclass of `Car`, which is a subclass of `Vehicle` what kind of objects can be added to the following collection?

```
List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I found [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) question, but still don't get it.

Thank you in advance!

LE: it's important to know how inheritance works in this case

Comment: The diamond operator is just syntactic sugar for typing whatever's in the left hand set of angle brackets. So in this case, it's exactly the same as `List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Car` or any subclass of `Car`. No superclass of `Car` though.

Edit: As @HotLicks mentioned, you can **technically** add an object of any type to the `List`, if you use subterfuge, by casting. Note that this is an easy way to confuse the hell out of yourself though, because you will be pulling an object out of your `List` and it will have an unexpected type.

```
import java.util.*;

class Foo{}
class Bar extends Foo{}
class Z{}
public class FooBar2{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Foo());
        list.add(new Bar());

        // Compile error
//        list.add(new Z());

        // Subterfuge
        ((List) list).add(new Z());
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, with subterfuge you can add essentially any object to `list`.

Comment: @HotLicks, By subterfuge, you mean Reflection?

Comment: @HotLicks, Somehow that does not seem like a good idea to do. :P

Answer (score 0):

The diamond operator is just a syntax simplification improvement that come with new feature of Java 7 ,

in Java 6 we write :

```
Map<City, Set<Person>> group=new HashMap<City, Set<Person>>();
```

but in java 7 we can just write ;

```
Map<City, Set<Person>> group=new HashMap<>();
```

for  the question 'what kind of objects can be added to the following collection' you can add any subclass of the class Car , RaceCar for example.