# Java Program throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to write a program to create a media object, I created the Cassette class which inherits from Audio which inherits from Media. I'm getting a null pointer exception and I have been trying for hours to fix it but I have no idea why it's being thrown. I appreciate your help in advance, thank you.

In my application class I initiate the following:

`static Media[] collection = new Media[100];`

And later on in the code I try to create a new Cassette object but it gives me the said null pointer exception.
The code I have is:

```
  collection[collection[0].getNumItems()] = new Cassette(cTitle, cMajorArtist, cPlayingTime, cNumPlays, cNumGroupMembers, cGroupMembers, pArtist, cNumSongs, cSongs);
```

All of the items being passed into the Cassette are all user input data.  It compiles fine but it's just when I run it that I get an error.

**EDIT**
Here is the numItems value in my media class.
`static int numItems = 0;`
And the method to return the number of items:

```
public int getNumItems()
   {
      return numItems;
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `collection[0]` should be and why do you think so?

Comment: It's being used to get the number of items and creating a new Cassette

Comment: What value do you think it has and why do you think so?

Comment: It should give me 0 because that's the value that `numItems` has in my Media class.  And I looked at an example from someone close to me and that's what they had in their piece of code which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). With the [*diamond operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/2970947) that would look something like,

```
static List<Media> collection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can use [`List#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29)

```
collection.add(new Cassette(cTitle, cMajorArtist, cPlayingTime, 
    cNumPlays, cNumGroupMembers, cGroupMembers, pArtist, cNumSongs, cSongs));
```

**Edit** If you want to use the array type, then this

```
collection[collection[0].getNumItems()]
```

Should be

```
collection[Media.getNumItems()]
```

To call the `static getNumItems()` in `Media`. Which *should* be

```
public static int getNumItems()
{
  return numItems;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the array answer, it saved me from having to rewrite my code.  It did the trick! Thank you!