# Why does my class cause 'NullPointerException' when I try to add a string to my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FriendList {

    private ArrayList<String> friendList;

    public FriendList() {
        ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addFriend(String friend) {
        friendList.add(friend);
    }

    public String getFriends() {
        return friendList.toString();
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things but can't seem to manage to add strings to the array list. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 10):

Your constructor initializes a local `ArrayList` variable, so your `friendList` member is never initialized.
When you try to access the uninitialized member in other methods, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Change

```
public FriendList() {
    ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

to

```
public FriendList() {
    friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: and even better: friendList = new ArrayList<>() if you are on Java 1.7

Comment: @DavidSoroko why do you consider this better? Is it only because you don't have to type 6 letters more?

Comment: And one of them is capital ;-). Have a look at this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7 
One could change `private ArrayList<String> friendList` to `private ArrayList<CharSequence> friendList` in one place only and everything would still compile.

Comment: @DavidSoroko after I saw this example, your answer makes sense. I was afraid what would happen if you changed `private ArrayList<String> friendList` to `private ArrayList<Integer>` and tried to add `String` there, but according to this example compiler shouldn't let it go. I simply thought `ArrayList()` and `ArrayList<>()` worked in the same way. And with this raw type, adding `String` to `ArrayList<Integer>` would make nice runtime crash, that wouldn't be prevented by compiler. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

You're hiding `friendList` field.

Use instead:

```
public FriendList() {
    friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

In your constructor, you instantiate a local variable `friendList`.

Answer (score 2):

**You are not initializing the instace member but creating and setting a list local to the constructor. It dies outside the scope of the constructor.**

So basically you are trying to add strings to a list that has not been created yet.

One other thing to note  from this post is **Java sets all it uninitialized objects/instances to null** Hence the Exception . Change this

```
public FriendList() {
    ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

to

```
public FriendList() {
    friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The friendsList list that you create inside the constructor is a local variable that hides the global friendsList. So, to solve your problem right now, just replace the line

```
   ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

with

```
   this.friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After that, you have to take a look at [variable scope principles.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html) The most of them are common for all programming languages

Answer (score 0):

OR you can change like this

```
public FriendList() {
    ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
to
public FriendList() {
    this.friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```