# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer

Tags: java, generics

I have written a generic class and below is the constructor of the class. I want to do something like this as written in line

```
elements = (E[])new Object[size]
```

Because I do not know the generic type on the run time therefore it will throw an exception.

```
public class Stack<E> implements IStack<E> {
protected E[] elements = null;
protected int top = -1;
protected int size= 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

public Stack(){
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}

public Stack(int size){
    if(size <0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial capacity cannot be negative or zero");
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    elements = (E[])new Object[size];
}
}
```

Is there any way to solve such problems? The declaration of E is

```
protected E[] elements = null;
```

This is how I am trying to call

```
Random ran = new Random();
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
st.push(ran.nextInt(100));
```

**Update**
Guys, Thanks for the help. I was messing around with generics so the problem was being created. Here is all the code which created the problem -

```
public class StackMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinMaxStack minMaxStack = new MinMaxStack();
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            minMaxStack.push(ran.nextInt(100));
        }
        System.out.println(minMaxStack);
    }
    }

public class MinMaxStack extends Stack<Integer> implements IMinMaxStack<Integer>{

private int min;
private int max;
/*
 * Approach 1:
 * For push method we can push and update the minimum/maximum value 
 * For pop method we will be traversing whole stack to find out the new minimum/maximum
 *
 */
@Override
public void push(Integer element){
    if(isEmpty()){
        this.min = element;
        this.max = element;
        elements[top+1] = element;
        size++;
    }else{
        if(element < min){
            min = element;
        }
        if(element > max){
            max = element;
        }
        elements[top+1] = element;
        size++;
    }
}
}

public  class Stack<E> implements IStack<E> {
protected E[] elements = null;
protected int top = -1;
protected int size= 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

public Stack(){
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}

public Stack(int size){
    if(size <0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial capacity cannot be negative or zero");
    }
    elements = (E[])new Object[size];
}

public void push(E element) {
    ensureCapacity();
    elements[top+1] = element;
    size++;
}
}

public interface IStack<E> {    
public void push(E element );
}


public interface IMinMaxStack<E> extends IStack<E> {    
public int min();   
public int max();   
}
```

**Update 2**: 
Seems, other than passing the class type as mentioned in an answer below, there is no way we can do this.

Comment: How is `elements` declared?

Comment: @lea protected E[] elements = null;

Comment: @tobias_k Even if I do that, still the core problems remains what I am trying to solve here.

Comment: Try to generify your `Stack` class by using `class Stack<T extends E> { ... }`. Then just use `Stack<E>`. So you don't need to do class casting.

Comment: @tobias_k it is runtime error.

Comment: Can you show us the line where this happens as neither of these lines need to have a class cast exception.

Comment: @Everv0id I did not understand what you are trying to say? Both the  T and E would be generic? Here E is generic variable used.

Comment: For me, it gets weirder and weirder... With `Object[] os` and `T` being generic for `Integer`, `T[] ts = (T[]) os;` works fine, but `Integer[] is = (Integer[]) os;` doesn't... what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Please include the relevant code of class `Stack` including the class declaration as well as the stack trace. I cannot reproduce...

Comment: @tobias_k Strange. I am using jdk1.6

Comment: JDK 1.6 has been deprecated... no new (security) updates.

Comment: Do you have to use array? Generics + arrays = problems. You could avoid them by simply using `List<E>` instead of `E[]`.

Comment: I actually thought out that solution. But was wondering if there is some way to do with arrays. Thanks. :)

Comment: Just creating a new instance of your `Stack` (without the `IStack` interface) I can not reproduce your problem. No Exceptions.

Comment: @tobias_k Me neither and I explicitly set source & binary level and JDK to 1.6.

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code? Try to recompile your files.

Comment: Usually this sort of problem will happen any place you actually try to get out `stack.elements` and assign it to an `Integer[]`.  Can you provide your complete code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the most-minimal code necessary to reproduce your exception.

```
class Stack<E> {
    protected E[] elements = (E[])new Object[1];
}

class IntStack extends Stack<Integer> {
    void push(Integer i) {
        // subtly accessing elements as Integer[] which it's not
        elements[0] = i;
    }
}
```

Java generics are implemented with [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so after compilation, this code translates to something like this:

```
class Stack {
    protected Object[] elements = new Object[1];
}

class IntStack extends Stack {
    void push(Integer i) {
        // throws ClassCastException
        ((Integer[])elements)[0] = i;
    }
}
```

Clearly a `new Object[]` is not an `Integer[]`. Notice how the cast gets moved to somewhere you did not explicitly put it. This is why `(E[])new Object[size]` was an *unchecked cast* and displayed a warning.

Instead, you should use `Object[]` and perform the unchecked cast only when you need to return an element to the outside world.

```
class Stack<E> {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size;

    Stack(int len) {
        elements = new Object[len];
    }

    void push(E e) {
        elements[size] = e;
        size++;
    }

    E pop() {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
       E e = (E)elements[size - 1];
       size--;
       return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. That is how I did it now.

Comment: He doesn't need to declare it as `Object[]` -- his code as is (with `elements` declared as `E[]`) will work fine if he made `elements` `private`.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, when you do `(E[])new Object[size]`, it is a lie. The object's actual runtime class is `Object[]`, which is not a subtype of `E[]` for whatever `E` is (unless `E` is `Object`). So the cast is, theoretically, incorrect. However, this does not create any immediate problems because inside the `Stack` class, `E` is erased to its upper bound, in this case `Object`. So inside the `Stack` class, we can use `elements` as `E[]`, and put `E` in and get `E` out of it, with no problem.

A problem only occurs when the (incorrect) fact that `elements` is type `E[]` is "exposed" to the outside of the class, outside of the scope of the erasure of `E`, into a scope where someone has a concrete type argument for `E`. This usually happens when someone inadvertently makes `elements` public, or implements a method that returns it to the outside like

```
E[] getElements() {
    return elements;
}
```

Then on the outside of the class, someone has a `Stack<SomeSpecificType>`, and call this method, and expect a `SomeSpecificType[]`, which is not what it gets.

However, your `Stack` class does not have such a method. So how are you "exposing" `elements`? The answer is that `elements` is `protected`, and is therefore "exposed" to subclasses. In this case, the subclass, `MinMaxStack`, extends `Stack` with a specific type for `E`, therefore, it "sees" `elements` as a specific type of array, which it is not.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the usual way is to pass the `Class` into the constructor, and use [`Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) like

```
public Stack(Class<E> cls, int size){
    if(size <0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial capacity cannot be "
            + "negative or zero");
    }
    elements = (E[]) Array.newInstance(cls, size);
}
```

**Edit**

From your update, **please** don't use [raw-types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). With Java 7 and above you can use the [diamond operator `<>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) like

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>(); 
st.push(ran.nextInt(100));
```

With earlier versions you specify the generic type like

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>(); 
st.push(ran.nextInt(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's clear now. You're trying to create your `Stack` without generic type. Consider `Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();` instead.

Comment: Random ran = new Random();
 Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
 st.push(ran.nextInt(100));

Comment: Yes. When you write `Stack st = new Stack();`, java understands it as `Stack<Object> st = new Stack<Object>();`, it causes your `Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer` error. So u need to specify your actual type to pass `Integer` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would fix it, you should not ever do `(T[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];` instead an abstraction should be there for example `(T[]) new Comparable[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];`

```
public class ArrayStack<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Stack<T> {

private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 50;

private int top;
private T[] elements;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayStack() {
    this.elements   = (T[]) new Comparable[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    this.top        = 0;
}
}
```