# Diamond type are not supported at this language level

Tags: android, android-studio, diamond-operator

After importing a project into Android studio, if I want to compile or run the project it throws an error:

> Error:(61, 65) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
>   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Does anyone know what it is and how to solve it ?

Comment: `diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6` Seems like you are using JDK6 update it to JDK7 or JDK8.

Comment: @Apurva Thanks for your cm but my jdk is 7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android Studio (File -> Project Structure..., Properties tab), set the following values:

```
Source Compatibility == 1.7
Target Compatibility == 1.7
```

[image]

After this your build.gradle will have these entries:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Intellij Idea, you need to set the project language level (default for all modules) and the module(s) language level.

**File** --> **Project Structure** --> Under **Project Settings** --> Select **Project** --> **Project Language Level** --> Select ***7 - Diamons, ARM, multi-catch etc.*** or ***8 - Lambdas,type annoationsetc***. option and Click on **Apply**

[image: Click here to see the pic]

Answer (score 2):

Few days ago , I suffered from this . Just update your  **buildToolsVersion** Like below. And Upgrade Your **SDK**.

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but My buildToolsVersion is same as You

Comment: In fact i import Telegram source code from Github and face with these error https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/master/TMessagesProj

Comment: @Amir Please check this page https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle

Comment: I just Import project and wants to run it for the first time I change nothing :(

Comment: When i faced this prob. i just update my JDK & SDK . By the way please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7 link

Answer (score 2):

[Diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) is one of the new feature of Jdk 7. Please make sure you jdk version is 7 or not. Here is an example of diamond operator.

Here is an assignment statement :

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

With diamond operator :

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

**Edit**

Add that to your `build.gradle` ..

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij, at leat for me, the problem was that the target version for each module, specified under "Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Java Compiler", was wrong. [image]

Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 1):

With Android KitKat (buildToolsVersion 19) you can use the diamond operator, multi-catch, strings in switches, try with resources, etc. To do this, add the following to your build file:

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 7
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
```

Note that you can use minSdkVersion with a value earlier than 19, for all language features except try with resources. If you want to use try with resources, you will need to also use a minSdkVersion of 19.

You also need to make sure that Gradle is using version 1.7 or later of the JDK. (And version 0.6.1 or later of the Android Gradle plugin.)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide