# Java Generics - Redundant Type Initialization

Tags: java, generics

*I couldn't find an answer to this exact question anywhere else, but I apologize if it's a duplicate.*

I usually see generic initialization done like this, with the type parameter next to the reference type, **as well** as the object declaration:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
```

Or, in the "short-hand" method (since Java 7), using the diamond:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();
```

However, I noticed that the code still works after omitting the parameter type next to the object declaration like so:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box();
```

How come? Is this some compiler magic (I'm using NetBeans, by the way).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find a great answer to this general question here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box();
```

assigns a raw `Box` to `integerBox`, bypassing generic type checks. While that might look fine in this case, it isn't so great when you have something like

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
...
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList(strings);
```

If you do

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(strings);
```

then the compiler will detect the type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile that, you'll get a `warning: unchecked conversion`. This means that, when you initialize  `integerBox` to a raw type, even though it was declared as a generic type, the compiler will still bypass generic type checking.