# Arraylist split in -

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have an array list:

```
ArrayList<String> allText = new ArrayList<String>();
```

its content is like this:

```
[Alabama - Montgomery, Alaska - Juneau, Arizona - Phoenix, Arkansas - Little Rock, California - Sacramento, Colorado - Denver]
```

How can i split it into  2 array list such as:

```
List<String> states = new ArrayList<>(); : [Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas]

List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>(); : [Montgomery, Juneau, Phoenix, Little Rock]
```

I have this but it doesn't work, it gives me an error on allText (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(allText);) it wants a string and not an arraylist :

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(allText);

    List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" - ");
        states.add(parts[0]);
        capitals.add(parts[1]);
    }
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` means ?

Comment: it gives me an error on allText (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(allText);)  it wants a string and not an arraylist

Comment: Post that error message in your question (not everyone reads comments).

Answer (score 1):

> it gives me an error on allText (Scanner scanner = new
>   Scanner(allText);) it wants a string and not an arraylist

Since you are passing `ArrayList` object to `Scanner`. But there no such constructor.

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
    for(String str:allText)
    {
    String[] parts = str.split(" - ");
    states.add(parts[0]);
    capitals.add(parts[1]);
    }
```

Need `for` loop to to iterate `allText`. Since its a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a `Scanner` to go through all the elements in a `List`. A Scanner only works on a single String, not a list of them since that has a type of `List<String>` and not `String`. What you want to do is loop over the elements in the list:

```
for(String stateAndCapital : allText){
    String[] parts = stateAndCapital.split(" - ");
    states.add(parts[0]);
    capitals.add(parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (where the argument is a regular expression, `\\s+` is one or more whitespace. If it should be optional whitespace you could use `\\s*`). Then add the capital and state to it's respective list. Then I would display both with formatted IO. And with Java 7+ you can use the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7). Something like

```
List<String> allText = Arrays.asList("Alabama - Montgomery",
        "Alaska - Juneau", "Arizona - Phoenix",
        "Arkansas - Little Rock", "California - Sacramento",
        "Colorado - Denver");
List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>();
for (String both : allText) {
    String[] arr = both.split("\\s+-\\s+");
    states.add(arr[0]);
    capitals.add(arr[1]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
    String state = states.get(i);
    String capital = capitals.get(i);
    System.out.printf("The capital of %s is %s%n", state, capital);
}
```