# Specifying type parameter when initializing Arraylists in java in intellij

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea

I'm a former eclipse user who currently made the jump to intellij. So far it's been great but I've noticed something interesting.

In one of my projects I declared a List of type Document (a org.bson class) and initialized it with with an ArrayList of type Document. I immediately noticed that intellij threw a warning recommending that I "replace <Document> with <>"

So it's recommending I change:

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<Document>();
```

to

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is very odd. I've always created lists using the first convention. I'm not sure if this some java best practice I've never knew about or a problem with intellij. Any explanation?

Comment: That's the diamond operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: @azurefrog: OP isn't asking for the purpose of the diamond operator, but rather why their IDE is suggesting to remove the generic type.

Comment: The purpose of the diamond operator is, among others, to make an explicit type argument obsolete. In most such cases, explicitness is unnecessary. That's why Intellij warns you. Try to use the explicit type argument somewhere where it is necessary (some complicated generic inferrence cases), and Intellij won't warn you.

Comment: This is because the Java and not IntelliJ IDEA. By changing the version of Java in the IDE, you can do as it has done until now.