# How to send XML POST requests with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Is it possible to send `XML` `POST` requests with `spring`, eg `RestTemplate`?

I want to send the following xml to the url `localhost:8080/xml/availability`

```
<AvailReq>
  <hotelid>123</hotelid>
</AvailReq>
```

Also do I want to add custom http headers on each request dynamically(!).

How could I achieve this with spring?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First of all, define your `HTTP` headers, like following:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("header_name", "header_value");
```

You can set any `HTTP` header with this approach. For well known headers you can use pre-defined methods. For example, in order to set `Content-Type` header:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
```

Then define a `HttpEntity` or `RequestEntity` to prepare your request object:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);
```

If you somehow have access to the `XML` string, you can use `HttpEntity<String>`. Otherwise you can define a POJO corresponding to that `XML`. and finally send the request using `postFor...` methods:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/xml/availability", request, String.class);
```

Here i'm `POST`ing the request to the `http://localhost:8080/xml/availability` endpoint and converting the `HTTP` response body into a `String`.

Note, that in the above examples `new HttpEntity<String>(...)` can [be replaced with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) `new HttpEntity<>(...)` using JDK7 and later.

Comment: OK I see, thanks. I have auto generated `JAXB` classes from `XSD`s. How could I then let the `RestTemplate` convert these, if outgoing must be `application/xml` and response is `text/html`, but everything is just xml.

Comment: Use your `JAXB` class, say `SomeClass`, instead of `String`. In fact it would be `HttpEntity<SomeClass> request = ...`.

Comment: `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` will convert your `JAXB` class to `XML`. It should be registered by default. If for some reason it was not registered, register it manually.

Comment: For `HTML` response, you can set `Accept` header to `text/html`, if it's necessary. But still you could use `String` in your `postFor...` method as the expected body type.

Answer (score 11):

Find below for example to use a RestTemplate to exchange XML as String and receive a response:

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><AvailReq><hotelid>123</hotelid></AvailReq>";

    RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate();
    //Create a list for the message converters
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    //Add the String Message converter
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    //Add the message converters to the restTemplate
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlString, headers);

    final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/xml/availability", request, String.class);
```

Comment: Helpful answer for deserializing Soap xml via a url

Answer (score 5):

Below you find a complete example how to use a `RestTemplate` to exchange XML documents and receive a HTML response:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.header;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class XmlTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
        String htmlString = "<p>response</p>";
        String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><AvailReq><hotelid>123</hotelid></AvailReq>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));

        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080/xml/availability"))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andExpect(content().string(is(xmlString)))
                .andExpect(header("header", "value"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("<p>response</p>", MediaType.TEXT_HTML));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("header", "value");
        HttpEntity<Document> request = new HttpEntity<>(document, headers);

        final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/xml/availability", request, String.class);

        assertThat(response.getBody(), is(htmlString));
        mockServer.verify();
    }
}
```